# Android Studio fails to build

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have very strange problem, I have a project that has other dependencies. The project builds fine with gradle in command line, however when it comes to Android Studio I cannot make it work at all. I spend around 6 hours trying and I give up. The error I get from Android studio is

```
Gradle 'sample-app-project' project refresh failed:
     Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
     A problem occurred configuring project ':sample-app'.
     A problem occurred configuring project ':sample-app'.
     Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
     Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

It looks that it has problem with downloading the zip, but why would it work in terminal. To be honest I have been using Android Studio since it launched, but I never really understood how to use the Modules properly.

Why 'sample-app-project' is a top root module and it has 'Android-Gradle' and there is another module 'sample-app' which has both 'Android-Gradle' and 'Android'.

This is the log from Android Studio.

```
2013-06-10 22:45:02,910 [   5313]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342
2013-06-10 22:45:04,847 [   7250]   INFO - nject.config.XPathSupportProxy - XPath Support is not available
2013-06-10 22:45:04,869 [   7272]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/IntelliLang.xml file is null
2013-06-10 22:45:05,230 [   7633]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 2435 ms
2013-06-10 22:45:05,230 [   7633]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 1 files to update
2013-06-10 22:45:05,306 [   7709]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 76 ms
2013-06-10 22:45:05,380 [   7783]   INFO - t.AndroidGradleProjectResolver - Added to RMI/Gradle process classpath: [/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/android.jar, /usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/builder-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar, /usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/gradle-model-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar, /usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/gradle-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar, /usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/builder-model-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar]
2013-06-10 22:45:05,535 [   7938]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx512m -Dsun.rmi.transport.connectionTimeout=3600000 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/idea.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/resources_en.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/jna-utils.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/util.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/oromatcher.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/trove4j.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/log4j.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/picocontainer.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/jna.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/jdom.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/annotations.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/openapi.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/lib/extensions.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-1.6.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-1.6.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-1.6.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-1.6.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-1.6.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/android.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/builder-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/gradle-model-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/gradle-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/local/etc/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/builder-model-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeImpl org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.remote.impl.GradleTaskManager
2013-06-10 22:45:05,765 [   8168]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID: 50332/ExternalSystemFacadeImplb8fc4a33
2013-06-10 22:45:06,110 [   8513]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
2013-06-10 22:45:06,171 [   8574]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
2013-06-10 22:45:06,598 [   9001]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 22:45:06.589 [Connection worker] DEBUG o.g.t.i.provider.DefaultConnection - Tooling API provider 1.6 created.
        2013-06-10 22:45:06,675 [   9078]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 5900 ms
2013-06-10 22:45:06,787 [   9190]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 22:45:06.782 [Connection worker] DEBUG o.g.t.i.provider.ProviderConnection - Configuring logging to level: INFO
2013-06-10 22:45:06,809 [   9212]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Tooling API uses target gradle version: 1.6.
2013-06-10 22:45:06,907 [   9310]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/codeStyleSettings.xml file is null
2013-06-10 22:45:06,909 [   9312]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/projectCodeStyle.xml file is null
2013-06-10 22:45:07,134 [   9537]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/fileColors.xml file is null
2013-06-10 22:45:07,184 [   9587]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens
2013-06-10 22:45:07,254 [   9657]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Starting Gradle daemon
2013-06-10 22:45:07,286 [   9689]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Starting daemon process: workingDir = /home/mike/.gradle/daemon/1.6, daemonArgs: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java, -Xmx512m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -cp, /home/mike/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-launcher-1.6.jar, org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon, 1.6, /home/mike/.gradle/daemon, 60000, 265f142f-72b1-4380-86ca-b8922dddacec, -Xmx512m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8]
2013-06-10 22:45:07,313 [   9716]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Starting process 'Gradle build daemon'. Working directory: /home/mike/.gradle/daemon/1.6 Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /home/mike/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/gradle-1.6/lib/gradle-launcher-1.6.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 1.6 /home/mike/.gradle/daemon 60000 265f142f-72b1-4380-86ca-b8922dddacec -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2013-06-10 22:45:07,319 [   9722]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - An attempt to initialize for well behaving parent process finished.
2013-06-10 22:45:07,330 [   9733]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon'
2013-06-10 22:45:07,865 [  10268]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Process 'Gradle build daemon' finished with exit value 0 (state: DETACHED)
2013-06-10 22:45:07,872 [  10275]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - An attempt to start the daemon took 0.581 secs.
        2013-06-10 22:45:07,909 [  10312]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Connected to the daemon. Dispatching Build{id=22396036-8d04-4f3b-bba7-ab61d4b625a1.1, currentDir=/usr/local/etc/android-studio/bin} request.
        2013-06-10 22:45:11,295 [  13698]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
        2013-06-10 22:45:11,458 [  13861]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -
        2013-06-10 22:45:11,458 [  13861]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2013-06-10 22:45:11,465 [  13868]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -
        2013-06-10 22:45:11,465 [  13868]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - * What went wrong:
2013-06-10 22:45:11,465 [  13868]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - A problem occurred configuring project ':sample-app'.
2013-06-10 22:45:11,465 [  13868]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - >
        2013-06-10 22:45:11,466 [  13869]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
2013-06-10 22:45:11,472 [  13875]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - > Configuration with name 'default' not found.
2013-06-10 22:45:11,473 [  13876]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -
        2013-06-10 22:45:11,474 [  13877]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - * Try:
2013-06-10 22:45:11,480 [  13883]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        2013-06-10 22:45:11,481 [  13884]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -
        2013-06-10 22:45:11,487 [  13890]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - BUILD FAILED
2013-06-10 22:45:11,487 [  13890]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -
        2013-06-10 22:45:11,487 [  13890]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Total time: 5.162 secs
2013-06-10 22:45:11,615 [  14018]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask -
        java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at sun.proxy.$Proxy3.resolveProjectInfo(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy88.resolveProjectInfo(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1$1.compute(RemoteUtil.java:104)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:165)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:101)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy88.resolveProjectInfo(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:328)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:369)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:502)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:185)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:229)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:175)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:404)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:460)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:155)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeImpl$2.invoke(ExternalSystemFacadeImpl.java:154)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy3.resolveProjectInfo(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':sample-app'.
        A problem occurred configuring project ':sample-app'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
        Configuration with name 'default' not found.
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:111)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:96)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:75)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:42)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
... 20 more
2013-06-10 22:45:11,620 [  14023]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Access is allowed from event dispatch thread only.
Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 3,4,Idea Thread Group] 371159127
Our dispatch thread:Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1 0.1.3#AI-130.700763, eap:true,6,Idea Thread Group] 562082350
SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1 0.1.3#AI-130.700763, eap:true,6,Idea Thread Group] 562082350
java.lang.Throwable
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:62)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.assertIsDispatchThread(ApplicationImpl.java:1130)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.assertIsDispatchThread(ApplicationImpl.java:1118)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.setTitle(ToolWindowImpl.java:358)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.task.ui.AbstractExternalSystemToolWindowFactory.createToolWindowContent(AbstractExternalSystemToolWindowFactory.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.ensureContentInitialized(ToolWindowImpl.java:448)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.getToolWindowElement(ExternalSystemUtil.java:121)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.notification.ExternalSystemIdeNotificationManager.processExternalProjectRefreshError(ExternalSystemIdeNotificationManager.java:43)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:347)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:369)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:502)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:185)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:229)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:175)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:404)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:460)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:155)
2013-06-10 22:45:11,624 [  14027]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Android Studio (I/O Preview) AI-130.700763  Build #AI-130.700763
2013-06-10 22:45:11,624 [  14027]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.6.0_27
2013-06-10 22:45:11,624 [  14027]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
2013-06-10 22:45:11,624 [  14027]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
2013-06-10 22:45:11,624 [  14027]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Linux
2013-06-10 22:45:11,624 [  14027]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action:
2013-06-10 22:45:11,625 [  14028]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Access is allowed from event dispatch thread only.
Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 3,4,Idea Thread Group] 371159127
Our dispatch thread:Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1 0.1.3#AI-130.700763, eap:true,6,Idea Thread Group] 562082350
SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1 0.1.3#AI-130.700763, eap:true,6,Idea Thread Group] 562082350
java.lang.Throwable
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:62)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.assertIsDispatchThread(ApplicationImpl.java:1130)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.assertIsDispatchThread(ApplicationImpl.java:1118)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.getTitle(ToolWindowImpl.java:342)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.setTitle(ToolWindowImpl.java:359)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.task.ui.AbstractExternalSystemToolWindowFactory.createToolWindowContent(AbstractExternalSystemToolWindowFactory.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.ensureContentInitialized(ToolWindowImpl.java:448)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.getToolWindowElement(ExternalSystemUtil.java:121)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.notification.ExternalSystemIdeNotificationManager.processExternalProjectRefreshError(ExternalSystemIdeNotificationManager.java:43)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:347)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:369)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:502)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:185)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:229)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:175)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:404)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:460)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:155)
2013-06-10 22:45:11,625 [  14028]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Android Studio (I/O Preview) AI-130.700763  Build #AI-130.700763
2013-06-10 22:45:11,625 [  14028]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.6.0_27
2013-06-10 22:45:11,625 [  14028]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
2013-06-10 22:45:11,625 [  14028]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
2013-06-10 22:45:11,625 [  14028]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Linux
2013-06-10 22:45:11,625 [  14028]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action:
2013-06-10 22:45:11,626 [  14029]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Access is allowed from event dispatch thread only.
Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 3,4,Idea Thread Group] 371159127
Our dispatch thread:Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1 0.1.3#AI-130.700763, eap:true,6,Idea Thread Group] 562082350
SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1 0.1.3#AI-130.700763, eap:true,6,Idea Thread Group] 562082350
java.lang.Throwable
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:62)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.assertIsDispatchThread(ApplicationImpl.java:1130)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.assertIsDispatchThread(ApplicationImpl.java:1118)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.getTitle(ToolWindowImpl.java:342)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.InternalDecorator.updateTitle(InternalDecorator.java:571)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.InternalDecorator.access$1500(InternalDecorator.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.InternalDecorator$ToolWindowHandler.propertyChange(InternalDecorator.java:870)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:298)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:291)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:229)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.setTitle(ToolWindowImpl.java:361)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.task.ui.AbstractExternalSystemToolWindowFactory.createToolWindowContent(AbstractExternalSystemToolWindowFactory.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.ensureContentInitialized(ToolWindowImpl.java:448)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.getToolWindowElement(ExternalSystemUtil.java:121)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.notification.ExternalSystemIdeNotificationManager.processExternalProjectRefreshError(ExternalSystemIdeNotificationManager.java:43)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:347)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:369)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:502)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:185)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:229)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:175)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:404)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:460)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:155)
2013-06-10 22:45:11,626 [  14029]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Android Studio (I/O Preview) AI-130.700763  Build #AI-130.700763
2013-06-10 22:45:11,626 [  14029]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.6.0_27
2013-06-10 22:45:11,626 [  14029]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
2013-06-10 22:45:11,627 [  14030]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
2013-06-10 22:45:11,627 [  14030]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Linux
2013-06-10 22:45:11,627 [  14030]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action:
2013-06-10 22:46:11,920 [  74323]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Process finished with exit code 0
2013-06-10 22:47:54,625 [ 177028]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 25 project components initialized in 14 ms
2013-06-10 22:47:54,625 [ 177028]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms
2013-06-10 22:47:54,675 [ 177078]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/applicationLibraries.xml file is null
```

I do not think that there is a problem with gradle build/settings files because I can install the app onto the device from command line. I am running the newest version of Android Studio 1.6.0_27 and I have both gradle wrapper and gradle 1.6 installed locally. I have linux debian wheezy.

Thank you for help

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that my gradle setup is as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/16974411/2368981 see Xavier response.

Answer (score 1):

Check this instructions http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Is oficial instrucction for Android.

Comment: Yeah I just been looking at it now. I converted my project to gradle manually, and as I said before it builds fine with gradle in command line. There is a problem with gradle plugin in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Check the topic troubleshooting here https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchChatAndroid for the same problem.

Comment: Where is the troubleshooting section there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to the newest version of Android Studio: 1.0 RC1

You can get it here: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is just better to restart from  scratch. Please check these type of posts, for example: [How to completely uninstall android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio).

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I disabled Scala and the error disappeared.
I think updating your plug-ins  after updating Android Studio may also work.