# How to completely uninstall Android Studio on Mac?

Tags: macos, android-studio, uninstallation

I recently downloaded Android Studio on my Macbook Pro and I messed up with it every time I open it. It gives me plugin errors and several other errors. I need to uninstall it completely from my mac. I tried to delete it from my mac and then install it again as if you would do the first time, but it did nothing and now the same problems occur.

**How can I manage to remove it completely and install a fresh one again?**

Comment: The latest versions of Android Studio for M1 chips have some errors.
The following link may enable you to make a successful installation after completely removing existing installations.
1. https://programhub.net/install-android-studio-on-apple-silicon-m1-m1-pro-m1-max-macbooks/
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Mq560sg-Mw

Answer (score 1634, accepted):

Execute these commands in the terminal (excluding the lines with hashtags - they're comments):

```bash
# Deletes the Android Studio application
# Note that this may be different depending on what you named the application as, or whether you downloaded the preview version
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
# Delete All Android Studio related preferences
# The asterisk here should target all folders/files beginning with the string before it
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/Google/AndroidStudio*
# Deletes the Android Studio's plist file
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*
# Deletes the Android Emulator's plist file
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*
# Deletes mainly plugins (or at least according to what mine (Edric) contains)
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio*
# Deletes all logs that Android Studio outputs
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio*
# Deletes Android Studio's caches
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio*
# Deletes older versions of Android Studio
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*
```

If you would like to delete all **projects**:

```bash
rm -Rf ~/AndroidStudioProjects
```

To remove gradle related files (caches & wrapper)

```bash
rm -Rf ~/.gradle
```

Use the below command to delete all **Android Virtual Devices**(AVDs) and keystores.

***Note**: This folder is used by other Android IDEs as well, so if you still using other IDE you may not want to delete this folder)*

```bash
rm -Rf ~/.android
```

To delete Android SDK tools

```bash
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*
```

Emulator Console Auth Token

```bash
rm -Rf ~/.emulator_console_auth_token
```

Thanks to those who commented/improved on this answer!

---

## Notes

1. The flags for `rm` are case-sensitive[<sup>1</sup>](https://linuxacademy.com/community/posts/show/topic/7331-r-flag-vs-r-flag-and-case-sensitivity-question) (as with most other commands), which means that the `f` flag must be in lower case. However, the `r` flag can also be capitalised.
2. The flags for `rm` can be either combined together or separated. They don't have to be combined.

### What the flags indicate

1. The `r` flag indicates that the `rm` command should-

   > a*ttempt to remove the file hierarchy rooted in each file argument.* - **DESCRIPTION** section on the manpage for `rm` (See `man rm` for more info)
2. The `f` flag indicates that the `rm` command should-

   > a*ttempt to remove the files without prompting for confirmation, regardless of the file's permissions.* - **DESCRIPTION** section on the manpage for `rm` (See `man rm` for more info)

Comment: Please add removing paths. Here is a complete thread about where path settings appear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: @Simon, Where is the Windows instructions?

Comment: @Pacerier I suggest you to open a new question at SF. I'm not a Windows user, but you can try to uninstall it from the control panel.

Comment: Also remove `/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/` folder. In my case it occupied 17G!

Comment: I think you'll also want to remove /usr/local/bin/adb.

Comment: @Simon add this `rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*` as well

Comment: @ShanXeeshi i don't have this folder in my computer.. what is this folder about?

Comment: @Simon you must have this folder under your USER. May be you are checking on wrong path. Its under Users -> Your User Name

Comment: +1 for @ShanXeeshi. I did have this directory : ~/.AndroidStudio1.5/ which needed to be removed. Simon: Great work for the perfect answer!

Comment: You can also edit your path in your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` if you're using that. Mine had `Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:` and `Users/user/Librabry/Android/sdk/tools` in it. Those sections can be removed

Comment: There is also the additional com.android.Emulator.plist file located in ~/Library/Preferences/

Comment: if it wasn't for Apples amazing 2mb hard drives.

Comment: @Simon, I used one command to install android sdk and didn't notice that there was one `--all` flag at the end, after half an hr i get a notification on my mac saying that I am running out of space. I did the steps mentioned above but only 15gb got free, before installing SDK through command line I had 80+gb free. How can I know where the sudo update android-sdk command would have saved the files?

Comment: @sahil  did you use homebrew to install the android-sdk? if so, use `brew uninstall android-sdk`.    or try this handy tool for finding large files in your Mac www.derlien.com

Comment: @Simon I had this issue where when I executed **react-native run-android** it used to say you have not accepted license. I already had android studio and sdk, but then I did this command, `android update sdk --no-ui --all`, and then it took up 80gb in no time, then I followed your answer but could only get 15gb free. It still shows in my system that it has 90gb of data in it, although I only have few apps.

Comment: @Simon that URL helped me, it showed the location of the folder with 67gb of data, dont know why it installed it there under `/usr/local/var/lib`, even android studio was not picking it up.

Comment: What about `~/.emulator_console_auth_token` ?

Comment: Don't forget environment variables

Comment: I think there is another "~/Library/Preferences/com.google.gct.plist" should be covered as well

Comment: As for the SDK, mine was located at `~/Android/android-sdk-macosx`.

Comment: If you're working with NativeScript, then run also this

`brew cask uninstall android-sdk`

Comment: Newer versions of android studio use this directory `rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio*`

Comment: What about the Intel HAXM extension in `/Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext`? Appeared to be a later version of what Apple had installed. Also seems Apple signed their version *Apple Inc.* whereas the later version is signed *Intel Inc.* — which I have not allowed in System Preferences > Privacy & Security.

Comment: this too `rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio*`

Comment: If you installed Android Studio with Jetbrains Toolbox, you may need to remove the application with `rm -Rf ~/Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/Android\ Studio.app` instead.

Answer (score 75):

Run the following commands in the terminal:

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.gradle  
rm -Rf ~/.android  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*  
rm -Rf /usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/
```

To delete all projects:

```
rm -Rf ~/AndroidStudioProjects
```

Comment: Note that it's a good idea to add comments on what each line does, for those who are skeptical of what the commands do, or for those who are curious.

Comment: also, if anyone not like to run the command then can use Shift + ⌘  + G on finder and paste the path to check the folder/file in finder.

Answer (score 27):

For someone using Android Studio 4.0 or above on MacOS 10.15.1 or above. Using command line blow:

```
# Deletes the Android Studio application
# Note that this may be different depending on what you named the application as, or whether you downloaded the preview version
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
# Delete All Android Studio related preferences
# The asterisk here should target all folders/files beginning with the string before it
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/Google/AndroidStudio*
# Deletes the Android Studio's plist file
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*
# Deletes the Android Emulator's plist file
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*
# Deletes mainly plugins (or at least according to what mine (Edric) contains)
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio*
# Deletes all logs that Android Studio outputs
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio*
# Deletes Android Studio's caches
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio*
# Deletes older versions of Android Studio
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*
```

Difference

Library/Preferences/***Google***/AndroidStudio*

Library/Logs/***Google***/AndroidStudio*

Library/Caches/***Google***/AndroidStudio*

Comment: You forgot about ~/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio*

Comment: that works for me only deleting this folder

Answer (score 19):

I was also facing same kind of problem on my Macbook Pro. I took these very simple steps and freshly installed Android Studio.

** **Link Contains Images, look if facing any problem.**

These Very Simple Steps Can Solve Your Problem.

1. Type "Command+option+Space Bar"
2. Type "Android Studio"
3. Click '+' button just below search box.
   [image]
4. A new bar will come up "Kind" is "any" click on "kind" --> Others -->  search for "system file" and select that by putting a tick mark.! And click on Ok.
   [image]
5. Then select "are included" from the drop down menu !
6. Then you get a lot of system file that need to be deleted to complete the fully un-installation of any app.
7. Click "command+A" to select all files and take a look on the file remove is some video files are also included. And click "command + Delete"
8. Empty your trash. Done

Answer (score 15):

You may also delete gradle file, if you don't use gradle any where else:

```
rm -Rfv ~/.gradle/
```

because .gradle folder contains cached artifacts that are no longer needed.

Comment: It would help to know what deleting the gradle folder does specifically too.

Comment: careful with this method, any document that contains the search words 'android studio' will be included, and deleted if you do a select-all + delete.

Answer (score 12):

Some of the files individually listed by *Simon* would also be found with something like the following command, but with some additional assurance about thoroughness, and without the recklessness of using rm -rf with wildcards:

```
find ~ \
  -path ~/Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari -prune -o \
  -iname \*android\*studio\* -print -prune
```

Also don't forget about the SDK, which is now separate from the application, and ~/.gradle/ (see *vijay*'s answer).

Answer (score 0):

I chanced upon one other directory which should be deleted (had a date of April 2021 on my system):

rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Android\ Open\ Source\ Project*

...and with credit to Hu1buerger of https://gist.github.com/talal/25d6b05b6969c2a8459b2b3abb86481f

rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains*