# Android Studio: Cannot Get Preview Window Opened

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have looked around and cannot find a solution to my answer.

I want the preview and design tab for my layouts, but they are not there. I go into View > Windows and it is greyed out. It is a stock project and I have not done any changes to it.
Here is an image of my problem

http://s22.postimg.org/dk7mo1w6p/screenshot1.png

Comment: I have this problem as well on OSX Mavericks. I am using Android Studio 0.5.3 but I have tried to roll back to some previous as well. I have tried all the suggestions I could find here on Stackoverflow. My xml is at the right location  etc.   http://i1366.photobucket.com/albums/r763/lla80/ScreenShot2014-04-02at083429_zps69a15114.png

Comment: I got mine to work now. I followed the remove instructions from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18458893/1165581 and then I installed 0.3.7 which had a specific fix for designer not being able to load. Now mine works again, but I have not updated to latest release.