# Android Studio 0.5.8 freezes on importing new project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio 0.5.8 freezes when new project is imported. 
This issue is observed only for "import project" and opening existing projects works fine. 
Also for freezing projects the build executes successfully on the command line via the gradle wrapper
I am using Android studio 0.5.8 in a multiproject setup with gradle plugin 0.10

[image: Snapshot for Android Studio Freeze]

Just before the project freeze Android Support Repository related warning can be observed in Gradle sync window. Not sure if this is related to the freeze issue though. 
I have the Android support repository correctly setup via the SDK manager and the project structure in Android studio points to the correct android sdk path.

[image: Android Support Repository Installed via sdk manager]

I've logged a bug for this issue as well. [Open Bug Logged](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69688)
If someone has faced a similar issue, kindly advise (orz)

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, any suggestions?

Comment: It complaining about the support repository is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68834, though I don't think that's the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Just an update on this. 
Completely un-installing Android Studio and re-installing seems to solve the issue.

By complete un-install, I mean not only removing it from the /Applications folder (on Mac OS) but essentially following the steps mentioned in this discussion : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio

After a complete un-install and reinstallation of AS v0.5.8, the project import now works fine. 

Thanks!