# Downgrading Android Studio cause unrecoverable error

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently attempted to upgrade my version of Android Studio, Android build tools and the Android Gradle Plugin to 0.6.1, 19.1.0 and 0.11.1, respectively.

That turned out to be a mess.  So much has changed, especially with the location of output files, that it made my project completely barf.  So now I want to downgrade back to 0.5.9, when everything worked and was fine, but I can't.

I get the message:

```
Error:Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ExtIdeaCompilerOutput' This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file
```

I've seen a few bugs in the google code forums about this issue, but no mention of any workaround.

I've tried completely wiping my previous install using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio),

And recloning my repo from a place that was known to work with AS 0.5.9 and gradle plugin 0.10.0, but no luck.

So currently I'm dead in the water.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70923, though that report doesn't have any useful information that would help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally solved this for me was uninstalling, via the instructions in this post,

[How to completely uninstall Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio)

and then installing 0.5.9 from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing just happened to me. Clearing the IDE's cache solved the issue

- In Android Studio
- File > Invalidate caches / restart...

Comment: I got that issue in android 2.0 Preview, its worked fine. Thank you so much

Comment: worked for me Android studio 2 but have to update the build-tools first as well