# Receiving Gradle build faliure in android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to import the [ongakuer/CircleIndicator](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator) sample project in Android studio and run it. But as soon as I browse for the project and click Import, the Android Studio hangs and the progress bar is shown indefinitely. I looked up and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29987664/4959077) answer. When I typed `./gradlew build`, I got error: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception`.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyScript(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$000(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$1.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_83zfpf7rvd1mwpdnuoofiqnhr.run(/Users/vishal/Downloads/CircleIndicator-master/circleindicator/build.gradle:29)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sonatypeRepo for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
    at upload_6f6p9mr1olnxg8bfrlu79isjn$_run_closure2_closure5.doCall(/Users/vishal/Downloads/CircleIndicator-master/circleindicator/upload.gradle:18)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.addRepository(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultMavenRepositoryHandlerConvention.mavenDeployer(DefaultMavenRepositoryHandlerConvention.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at upload_6f6p9mr1olnxg8bfrlu79isjn$_run_closure2.doCall(/Users/vishal/Downloads/CircleIndicator-master/circleindicator/upload.gradle:14)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:63)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:482)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:55)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$ContainerElementsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:324)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
    at upload_6f6p9mr1olnxg8bfrlu79isjn.run(/Users/vishal/Downloads/CircleIndicator-master/circleindicator/upload.gradle:12)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 46 more
```

When I tried running `./gradlew --info clean`, I got this:

```
./gradlew --info clean
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/Users/vishal/Downloads/CircleIndicator-master/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Users/vishal/Downloads/CircleIndicator-master/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'CircleIndicator-master', project ':circleindicator', project ':sample']
Evaluating root project 'CircleIndicator-master' using build file '/Users/vishal/Downloads/CircleIndicator-master/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':circleindicator' using build file '/Users/vishal/Downloads/CircleIndicator-master/circleindicator/build.gradle'.
Creating configuration compile.
Creating configuration publish.
Creating configuration provided.
Creating configuration wearApp.
Creating configuration androidTestCompile.
Creating configuration androidTestPublish.
Creating configuration androidTestProvided.
Creating configuration androidTestWearApp.
Creating configuration testCompile.
Creating configuration testPublish.
Creating configuration testProvided.
Creating configuration testWearApp.
Creating configuration debugCompile.
Creating configuration debugPublish.
Creating configuration debugProvided.
Creating configuration debugWearApp.
Creating configuration testDebugCompile.
Creating configuration testDebugPublish.
Creating configuration testDebugProvided.
Creating configuration testDebugWearApp.
Creating configuration releaseCompile.
Creating configuration releasePublish.
Creating configuration releaseProvided.
Creating configuration releaseWearApp.
Creating configuration testReleaseCompile.
Creating configuration testReleasePublish.
Creating configuration testReleaseProvided.
Creating configuration testReleaseWearApp.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/vishal/Downloads/CircleIndicator-master/circleindicator/upload.gradle' line: 18

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No such property: sonatypeRepo for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 18.432 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

As evident from the logs, there is some problem in `upload.gradle`. Here it is:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

group = "me.relex"

configurations {
    archives {
        extendsFrom configurations.default
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    configuration = configurations.archives
    repositories.mavenDeployer {

        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: sonatypeRepo) {
            authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername,
                    password: sonatypePassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'CircleIndicator'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'a lightweight viewpager indicator like in nexus 5 launcher'
            url 'https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator'

            scm {
                url 'scm:git@github.com:ongakuer/CircleIndicator.git'
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:ongakuer/CircleIndicator.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:ongakuer/CircleIndicator.git'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'relex'
                    name 'relex'
                    email 'wwwliangxin@gmail.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

signing {
    required { has("release") && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: ./gradlew --info clean   and chek  the stdout for added detail on error

Comment: @RobertRowntree: see the edit in question

Comment: where is "sonatypeRep" getting its value from?  try in place of that propertyname the actual string value for where that repo exists ie the URL in place of 'sonatypeRepo"