# Why Android ddms not showing emulator or connected devices?

Tags: android, android-emulator, ddms

This is a screenshot of my DDMS. As you can see there is nothing and I cant find any way to get the devices list or any other functional parts.

[image]

I try to reinstall android studio and new sdk but still its not solved. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: It seems your DDMS is broken...

Comment: How can I fix this. Its been very long time I can't found any solution for this. Even I install new Android studio but still I found this DDMS.

Comment: I am not sure, maybe reset it or find the related files and reinstall

Comment: Can you please give me some idea how to reset it?

Comment: Anybody found a solution to thi

Comment: At `HOME/.android/` delete `ddms.cfg` and `monitor-workspace` folder, then restart DDMS. It should work. If not completely uninstall the Android studio [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio) and reinstall it.:)

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this problem this afternoon, after half day of annoying work, I solved it at last.

The solution is, just delete *.cfg and monitor-workspace in $HOME/.android/.

Below is how I solved the problem.

There's little information about this problem. I guess it is a rare one.

I have tried several ways. First, reinstall the build tools, simply download and replace the tools directory. But it didn't work. And then I reinstalled the Android Studio, still not work either.

But during the procedure I have found that the ddms must have saved some cache in the computer. So I find the place `$HOME/.android/` in this [website](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html).

After delete all *.cfg(3 or 4) and monitor-workspace, my ddms works well again.
I guess delete all *.cfg is not necessary, just ddms.cfg. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Go to DDMS perspective -> Devices -> View menu(on right corner) -> Reset adb

If still not working, run this commands in command prompt/terminal

adb kill-server

adb start-server

Comment: device or anything will not be visible

Answer (score 1):

It was broken after latest Android SDK sync using Android Studio. To fix it, launched SDK manager using Eclipse, and installed SDK tools versions 24.01 and 19.1, and removed intermediate results.

Answer (score 1):

I had to right click on "DDMS" (perspective button) and click on reset to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try Window menu => show preview (select your necessary window view ).
[image]

and another try minimum /Maximum window button press

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This is **not Android Studio**. It's **Eclipse**!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not warking. :(

Answer (score 0):

Delete the **.android** directory in user home