# Execution failed for task 'app:mergeDebugResource'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting this "Execution failed for task 'app:mergeDebugResource'" error every time I try to build or clean my project. I have reinstalled Gradle, Java, Android Studio, and all of the SDKs several times, so it's not that. And none of the answers on StackOverflow seem to be helpful. I'm trying to learn Android development but can't because of this error. Please help!

Here are the results of Gradle build --stacktrace:

```
Dhruvs-MacBook-Pro:app dhruv$ gradle build --stacktrace
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                       
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE     
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE     
:app:checkDebugManifest                
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE     
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library                
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library                
:app:prepareDebugDependencies                 
:app:compileDebugAidl                 
:app:compileDebugRenderscript                 
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig                 
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:app:mergeDebugAssets                 
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugResources                 
:app:mergeDebugResources          
    /Users/dhruv/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication4/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res/values/values.xml: Error: org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
 :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED          

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
 >  /Users/dhruv/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication4/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res/values/values.xml: Error: org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl

 * Try:        
 Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

 * Exception is:
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: /Users/dhru/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication4/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res/values/values.xml: Error: org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
            at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.groovy:119)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: /Users/dhruv/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication4/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res/values/values.xml: Error: org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.postWriteAction(MergedResourceWriter.java:333)
     at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:48)
     at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:125)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:291)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.groovy:112)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
/Users/dhruv/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication4/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredAttrNSImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.dom.AttrImpl.setOwnerDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.dom.NamedNodeMapImpl.setOwnerDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl.setOwnerDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.adoptNode(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.NodeUtils.adoptNode(NodeUtils.java:49)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.postWriteAction(MergedResourceWriter.java:320)
    ... 57 more


BUILD FAILED  

Total time: 14.776 secs
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Execute this in terminal window and see,

```
          gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response - I'm still getting the same exact error :(

Comment: I had the same problem. Re-installing Android Studio with SDK helped solve it.

Comment: I just tried that - it didn't work - I even used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio to delete everything

Answer (score 0):

I had the error when installing new packages on my RN app.
I fixed the error by running

```
cd android/ && ./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies`
```

then

```
cd ../
```

again

```
react-native run-android
```