# Android Studio faces an issue on mac

Tags: android, android-studio

While using Android Studio on mac, I came into this popup message.

```
Low disk space on a Android Studio system directory partition.
```

I really can't figure out what this message is actually talking about. Please give me some guidance and that will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I think I'm being quite confused with the term 'partition' here. Does that refer to the free disk size?

Comment: A hard disk drive is sectioned in different sections named as partitions. A partition serves as a seperate logical volume. On windows partitions are shown like C:/, D:/ as an example

Comment: It might be possible, that your OS-Partition, where Android Studio is installed has no more free space available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAVA jdk and all sdk related file it May consume most of its disk space

Re-install Android Studio on a larger partition and it may solve your problem.

**How to Install android Studio :** https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

also make sure to also save AppData\Local\Android\sdk on the larger partition

Uninstall Android Studio :
[How to completely uninstall Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what exactly do you mean by partition?

Comment: Right that's the one I was confused about. Even though my mac is not partitioned, it keeps saying the partition stuff..

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to mac, and there might be something I'm not getting clear about the system.

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-view-information-about-partitions-and-volum.html

Comment: Hmm strange. My mac is single-partitioned so there should not be any issues with the partition. Besides there are more than 200 GBs left.

Comment: I think the problem is, once the application was installed it was placed on the smaller partition. reinstall it will work thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81553/discussion-between-anil-meenugu-and-marshall-darnley).