# Andrioid studio start fail: Fatal error initializing 'null'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I don't know what happened to  my Android studio，when I start it ，it shows me an error message like below. And I try to uninstall/reinstall it,but it doesn't work.Who can help me!!!

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'null'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'null'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentsRegistry.loadClasses(ComponentManagerImpl.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentsRegistry.loadClasses(ComponentManagerImpl.java:417)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentsRegistry.access$000(ComponentManagerImpl.java:403)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:504)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:486)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/X509HostnameVerifier : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:471)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:259)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:255)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:216)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:471)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:259)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:255)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:216)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.<clinit>(CertificateManager.java:81)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentsRegistry.loadClasses(ComponentManagerImpl.java:427)
    ... 24 more
```

> edit: os is mac ,the android studio versison is 1.3 Beta 1.0

Comment: Give more information. What is your OS? What version of AS? Did you remove all local files during uninstall?

Comment: Looks like it's trying to read a Java 7 class on a JVM that doesn't support it.

Comment: @JaredBurrows, os is mac ,the android studio versison is 1.3 Beta 1.0,I follow this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio) to uninstall

Comment: Beta? Why use the beta? Can you not just use the latest release?

Comment: @JaredBurrows yes,but I uninstall it and reinstall the latest release,it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OH,I solved it. The solution is to delete /Library/Java/Extensions  directory