# Android Studio Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager'

Tags: android, android-studio

This problem occurred when I upgraded Android Studio 3.0 to 3.1: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager $ StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager'
What caused this, how to solve this problem yet
The details of the problem are below：

[image: error1]

Answer (score 4):

I fixed that by:

1) Downloading [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)

2) Unzip the files in `Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\security`

3) Run Android Studio :)

Comment: Saved me alot.Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

1.
Try to delete IDE system folder >
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519

2.
Reinstall >
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

check if that helps

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem.

For me, all above methods are useless.

Then I guess maybe the plugin installed newly cause the error .

I empty the plugins at the directory of"C:\Users....AndroidStudio\config\plugins"
and it work normally.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps deleting last installed plugin would help. Path: C:\Users{username}}{AndroidStudio Version}\config\plugins\ .
In my case - could get launch after deleting Hoi4.jar , avaliables.xml, availables_etag. 
(https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112016425)

Answer (score 1):

As the exception occurred by uninstalling any plugin from plugin manager, that means you have just uninstalled any plugin. But in such case, plugin not fully uninstalled from android studio config.

So you need to delete that folder.

First goto task manager of the system, end task android studio if not ended.

Then goto installation folder USER/.AndroidStudioX.X/config/plugins, Now check that any folder regarding your uninstalled plugin. Delete that folder. Now start the android studio.

Works in my case.

Answer (score -2):

Update the IDE tools. It worked for me.
The Android SDK Manager helps you download the tools. To open the SDK Manager from Android Studio, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager in the toolbar.

[Here is the link for reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html)