# android studio can't open any projects or files in mac

Tags: android

I am using the latest Android Studio version 1.2.2. I can't open any projects or files suddenly. It only show the "no files are open" page. Most of the tools are grey.

I tried create a new project. The new project created successfully, but still stay in this "no files are open" page.

Please give me some suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've meet the same problem and have no any solution at all. I've restarted my mac, reinstalled Android Studio, deleted all my preferences, it had no any luck.

Comment: Same problem here. I was working on a project then when I opened up another one of my projects, it suddenly stopped working. This is annoying! I can't open any of my projects!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio can't open any projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128533/android-studio-cant-open-any-projects)

Answer (score 10):

Do you install Crashlytic (Fabric) plugin to Android Stuido??

If yes, try to uninstall the plugin and restart Android Studio. I've fixed this problem by uninstalling it. (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178464)

Comment: I have Crashlytic plugin and I'm having the same issue. How am I to remove the plugin completely?

Comment: @user3278616: Go to Preference -> Plugins, find the Crashlytics (or Fabric) Plugins, click Uninstall plugin and restart Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect. Works now. I love it when crash analytic software crashes.

Comment: @user3278616: OK, could you upvote my answer to let other people know this works, thank you.

Comment: Uninstalling the Fabric Plugin solved my problem. They've just updated the plugin and it messed up everything.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing exactly the same problem. Then, I completely removed Android Studio following this tutorial: [How to completely uninstall Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio), installed it again and I was able to open and run my projects as before.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Note to future readers with the same problem. Do this only as a last resort. Make sure to check the logs to confirm that crashlytics is the reason for this bug because I'd rather you uninstall the plugin rather than downloading android studio again and having to re-download all the support libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by uninstalling and re-installing the plugin. Now it works and my projects are openning. But still it's not giving me confidence.