# Android Studio Hangs/Freezes After Building/Running

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Android Studio hangs after every build/run for at least a few minutes (sometimes it does not release).
Also **Indexing** occurs quite often and takes a very long time.

Have tried:

1. Increasing HEAP
2. working offline
3. changing gradle versions (working with and without the wrapper)
4. deleting cache/restarting
5. reinstalling studio (and deleting everything using this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio)
6. syncing
7. rebuilding project
8. disabling unrelated plugins
9. unplugging device/genymotion

I have a Macbook Pro (2015) with 16GB i7 (turbo boosted)

*Hangs/Freezes means scrolling/typing or any other action takes a while to react.

Comment: Does it happen only with a specific project or with *any* project ?

Comment: It happens with medium/large projects. Small projects do not have a problem.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with a huge project I'm working on. It works a little better I increase the java heap - but still this is no way close to perfect...

Comment: I have the same problem on a small project only after running.

Comment: Did you solve this yet? How about trying in a docker? What happens when you build / install from the command line?