# Android Studio freezing every 10 secs

Tags: android, android-studio, freeze

Android Studio freezes for a few seconds every time. When tries to autocomplete, when loads gradle and even when i just open another directory! My computer has 16GB RAM core I7. I checked it's running processes and there is nothing overloading my computer. I found this log on Android studio just after a freeze action.

```
Received result Success[value=org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildActionResult@9ce896] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=4363, address=[1459bd31-811f-4cf0-8cfe-ad8b357eaff9 port:54982, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1, /127.0.0.1]], idle=true, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=014c14d9-e239-44bf-a401-d80b04b94f3c,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386,daemonRegistryDir=/home/ezequiel/.gradle/daemon,pid=4363,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}.
```

Comment: did you tried invalidated cache ? and open as fresh.

Comment: @codebased Thanks for answering. Yep i tried that but didnt work. :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently with Android Studio 2.3.3, starting to freeze on a regular base every three to five seconds, regardless of what the actual action was and independently from a running build or any other background activity.
Gradle definitely was not the culprit here, instead it seems that some plugin or configuration made it freeze.

I ended up partially following the steps here: [How to completely uninstall Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio), removing everything in `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.3` `~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio2.3`, `~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio2.3` and `~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio2.3`, which made CPU load go down from 100 to around 15 percent while being idle, making the freezing go away completely.

I'd loved to find out the real reason, considering the fact that this occurred on two different machines (at home and at work), which IMHO doesn't make it a "random" issue specific to only a single, weird configuration.