# Android Studio fails to resolve repository

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In my project, I'm trying to use the design support library.  I have in my Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.android.support:design'
    ....
}
```

And when I try to build this, I get the error:

[image]

Normally I would just click *`Install Repository and sync project`*, however, this seems to *not work anymore*.  Clicking this does absolutely nothing, even though clicking `Open File` works fine.

**How can I manually install it?**

I have the latest Android Support Repository (30.0.0), and Android Support Library (23.2.1) installed.

Comment: are you connected to the internet with proper proxy settings (if any) for android studio?

Comment: Try with Giving this `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`.

Comment: @jaydroider This technically works, because I think I have used that version previously.  However I am targeting api 19 and when I try to use `:19.0.0` it gives me the same error.  Is that the proper version for me to be trying?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic Yes.  The sdk manager has no problem updating packages.

Comment: @Timestretch What is your `compileSdkVersion`. Depend on that try to set whichever version is currently available.

Comment: @jaydroider compileSdk is 19, build tools version is 23.0.3, min sdk is 19, and target sdk is also 19.

Comment: See this link, uninstall android APP and SDK, it works for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is because you've not specified the version.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

change version to what you have downloaded.

Comment: it is not clickable with any version or not

Answer (score 5):

For me the solution was to add maven in the allprojects section. From the setup document: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

in the project level settings.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Then double check the document for the latest version.
In the app level of the settings.gradle file add:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
}
```

And use Gradle to sync the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can go **File->Settings->Gradle** Look at the "Offline work" inbox,

If it's checked you can uncheck and try to sync again.