# Android USB Debugging is not showing the authorization dialog

Tags: android, debugging, usb, authorization, adb

I need help with USB Debugging...

I've been trying to allow my computer to debug my phone for ages.
It has been frustrating. I have installed all required drivers. My device is detected through `adb devices` but it is unauthorized. No matter how much i try, the authorization dialog on my android is not showing up.

If you want to tell me to go to do something to the root files, i can't.
My phone is still original, and unrooted. Yes, i have changed to PTP. I also have installed the latest sdk platform tools from SDK Manager. I use windows, and using adb with cmd.

Please help!

Comment: Did you enable USB debugging in the developer settings on the phone?

Comment: `i have changed to PTP.` Try changing to **M**TP.

Comment: I have tried both modes. And, of course I have enabled the USB Debugging setting...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same Problem.
I solved it by manually copying my `adbkey.pub` (from `~/.android/`) to the phone at `/data/misc/adb/` and name it `adb_keys`. I placed the file via `mtp` on the internal sdcard and moved and renamed it in place with a filebrowser on the phone. Obviously you need a rooted phone to do that....

In short:
copy from your computer `~/.android/adbkey.pub` to the phone as `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`

Comment: Hi, I cannot see "~/.android" folder in my PC, for me "Allow USB Debugging" option is not showing up when mobile connected to PC.Please help me on this.

Comment: Thank god this saved my life. I didn't have to flash another ROM.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and tried everything from deleting the whole ~/.android folder to all possibles adb's terminal commands. The only solution was completely uninstalling Android Studio and Android SDK using these steps:
[How to completely uninstall Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

After that, I installed the latest version of Android Studio and everything worked normally. The authorization dialog appeared and the device was recognized.
With me the issue happened after upgrading my MacOS to High Sierra.