# Android Studio stalls at the loading screen

Tags: macos, android-studio

I've been having a lot of issues updating AS on my mac. Here's my current issue. I uninstalled my old version following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio) and downloaded the latest version from the android website. After mounting the dmg and placing AS in my applications folder, I try to launch it. However it stalls at the launch graphic. The loading bar moves all the way to the right and nothing else happens. Thoughts? Also, my JDK/JRE are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .android and .AndroidStudio1.5 folders in my user folder did the trick.