# Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)

Tags: android, permissions

i import my project from Eclipse to Android Studio V2.2.2 . but when Gradle build is finished i got this errors in my Logcat and one white screen showed on Emulator for 5-10 seconds. I have all the solutions available, but so far I have not found a solution to this problem. I apologize in advance for the poor English.

My LogCat while app is start running:
[image]

and my emulator screen:

[image]

Comment: check this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518133/android-studio-emulator-will-not-run-a-simple-hello-world-application, it looks similar problem

Comment: @petrumo thanks but this is not my solution.