# Android Studio 2.2 Designer (Gridlayout) not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gridlayout, android-studio-2.2

After the update to 2.2 the designer seems to gone crazy.
I using API 24 with Build Tools Version 24.0.3.

Into the designer if i have a parent GridLayout or the v7:

1. I can't drag the first subview inside. The only solution i found is that to drag it into the Component Tree.
2. If i add two subviews, i can't arrange them by dragging inside the designer, before the 2.2 version of android studio the columns and the rows was , now it shows this error and stops to respond:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.handlers.grid.GridDragHandler.commit(GridDragHandler.java:56)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.DragDropInteraction$1.run(DragDropInteraction.java:191)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:108)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:103)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.access$000(WriteCommandAction.java:34)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:85)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:723)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:82)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.DragDropInteraction.moveTo(DragDropInteraction.java:203)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.DragDropInteraction.end(DragDropInteraction.java:123)
>       ...

3. Sometimes into the designer if i click one subview of the GridLayout it goes at the bottom of the superview, in xml preview too!!!

Now the designer doesn't allow me to copy components between 2 different layouts ( i have to copy it from xml ).

If a property of a view is selected into the right panel ( for example : text for a TextView ) and i press delete, it deletes the components instead of resetting the property ( i have to delete the line from xml ).

It should be the stable version, but in my opinion, it's not usable like before, now i have to manually modify the xml more then before.

I already tried to clear all like: [Described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio) and then reinstall it. But it's the same.

It's something that i am missing?

Comment: Same issue here but via IntelliJ 2016.3. Layout editor is totally unusable for me with grid-layouts. It doesn't add layoutColumn or layoutRow. You can't drag things around in a sane fashion (it does random things) and it infrequently throws various exceptions from NPEs to other more obscure exceptions. 

Haven't tested on other layouts since my project uses grid mostly...

Comment: Yes, since the update 2.0 the grid designer is unusable. The only solution i found is that to insert the columns and the rows manually into the xml