# Android Studio on Mac OS does not show Android SDK in preferences

Tags: android, android-studio, preferences

I cannot see Android SDK section in Android Studio preferences! This is the preferences which i see:
[image: What is now!]

Can any one say how can i enable android SDK in preferences? It should be some thing like this:

[image: What it must be!]

**Edit:**
Some cashed data causes this problem and even invalidate cashes not worked for this problem. So Uninstall android studio (with it's data) completely and install it again works successfully.

Comment: you may be using a version of android studio different from the second screenshot. Try to hover on icons in top bar menu to see which displays a Android SDK pop up

Comment: you may be using a version of android studio different from the second screenshot. Try to hover on icons in top bar menu to see which displays a Android SDK pop up

Comment: I think you trying in `IntelliJ IDEA` `IDE`

Comment: What is the version of Android Studio you are using? And from which channel(stable, beta, canary)?

Comment: The version i use is android studio 2.2.2 and now i updated it to 2.2.3 . But does not works!

Comment: Both on them are the same version. The First one is on my Mac-Mini which not works and the second one is on my Macbook which is works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Once I uninstalled the android studio and installed it again but it doesn't works. 
Then again I uninstalled the android studio and it cashes completely according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio) post and installed it again. 
So it works and show Android SDK.