# Cannot run AVD emulator in Android Studio, missing file

Tags: android, emulation

I have a quite big problem as accidentally removed the file, it is already removed from the bin on Mac. Now in Android Studio I cannot run emulator and I get the below message:
[image: Error Message Android]

Can anyone help me please? What should I do now? Is there any way I can reinstall this missing file for Android studio?

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** My problem was a missing .exe file: qemu-system-i386. I couldn't find any working solution, tried installing various images versions, was creating new emulators. I decided to uninstall Android Studio and proceed with the new installation. I used a free tool, AppCleaner, to remove the Android Studio, you can read more about this here: http://lifehacker.com/5828738/the-best-app-uninstaller-for-mac. But still had to remove manually the entire sdk tools directory. You can actually do the same from the terminal, here is the thread how to do it: [How to completely uninstall Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio)

Anyway, the important thing it is working now! :D

Comment: Just try to create a new emulator, from there you'd see an option for downloading images. `Tools` -> `Android` -> `AVD Manager`

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I've already created the second one and got the same error, however not sure if I were installing images there, will double check this and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @azizbekian it does not work unfortunately:)  I select the recommended option for installing images but still have the same problem:(

Answer (score 0):

1) Open the SDK manager (see the image below):
 [[image: Open SDK Manager[1]]
2) Launch the stand alone SDK manager

3) Ensure that you have downloaded and installed the SDKs and tools for Android version that you'd like to emulate. In my case I use API 25. You should also have the Intel x86 Intel Atom System images installed.

[image: Stand alone SDK Manager]

4) Then open the AVD Manager and "Create a Virtual Device"

5) Select the API level that corresponds to the one you installed in the previous steps. In the newer versions of Android Studio you can also download and install the System Image you desire in this menu.

Comment: Hi @Adrian, thank you for this solution. I did the steps but still having this issue. It seems I have all the 25 API level images installed now. I also restarted Android Studio just to be sure. Any other ideas what can be wrong?