# How to resolve Android Studio cannot find JAR 'core-3.1.1.jar' required by module 'gradle-jetty?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, build.gradle

I opened up Android Studio today and for the first time I saw this error:
Error:Cannot find JAR 'core-3.1.1.jar' required by module 'gradle-jetty' using classpath or distribution directory '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1'

I have tried, restarted both my Mac and Android Studio but yet I still get this error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I had the same problem, follow the answer detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio) and re-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, follow the answered detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio) to uninstall, and then just re-install. Before importing any existing projects just create a dummy project to ensure that everything finishes installing correctly.

Then simply just tell your antivirus that the project folder for android studio is excluded from the virus searches.

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions in the exact same post you linked and everything is working fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my antivirus had removed the file.
An uninstall and fresh install of Android Studio was able to solve my problem.

Comment: That won't stop your Antivirus from deleting again

Comment: @cricket_007 it seems as if there was an issue with the AntiVirus itself as it was even identifying my own personal photos as infected.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Yeah, my Antivirus deleted the file too but it's seem uninstall and re-install Android Studio didn't work for me.

After re-install Android Studio, I can work normal with 1 project but when i try to open other project even create a new one, the 'core-3.1.1 jar' error show up again.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove ./gradle folder compeletely. 
Let Android Studio install Gradle from new or do it yourself.