# Android Studio NullPointerException (no error message) after grey screen/restart

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I was programming in Android Studio, on MAC OS X macOS Sierra.

I was debugging code on one emulator, then I started next emulator with different phone. Then accidentally laptop restarted (with the grey screen https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--HPvl05ih--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/18mfougmh04injpg.jpg).

After boot everything come back, Android Studio too. But I can't debug my apps. I have

```
Error:java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

This happening everytime I try to run my app.
It is on my company project, from git. I tried different versions of code.

I tried also (with chronology):

- reinstall Android Studio
- reinstall SDK, Virtual Devices
- reinstall Android Studio after completly delete it from Mac, using terminal ([How to completely uninstall Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio))
- reinstall Java (uninstall with the tip from Java webpage (https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml)

I don't know what I can do next besides reinstalling OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.

After that post I also tried cleaning cache, logs and again reinstall Java JDK. Nothing helped.

Unfortunately the only solution which helped - format and reinstall system.

Answer (score 0):

Try File -> Invalidate caches / Restart... in android studio.

Comment: Did not help. Thanks for a try

Answer (score 0):

you must remove ".gradle" folder into your root project and restart your android 
studio.

Comment: Try to explain why he should do that and what it will actually do