# Command lines to uninstall Android Studio don't apply for my setups on Mac. (OS X)

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

Below is how to uninstall Android Studio I learned from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio)

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*
```

If I do the first line above, I get

```
-bash: /Applications/Android Studio.app: No such file or directory
```

Also, I searched "library" folder, but it doesn't exist. So I went to "libraries" folder, and that one doesn't include preferences.

Why is it, and how can I uninstall Android Studio completely? Many thanks.