# Android studio 2.3 always hangs out

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

[image]I'm using Android Studio `2.3` within gradle `2.3.3`. I face a weird problem and being stuck for a week. It hangs out very often when I type some lines of code, right before it shows the `auto complete` box.
Or if I didn't type anything but use `Command-click`to find implementation of a variable or method, it show the dialog says `Resolving Reference` and hangs there.
Sometime, if I switch to another application for awhile and switch back to view Android Studio, it hangs as well.

I already tried many different methods but didn't help, including:

- Remove Android studio completely follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458893/523325) then download and install again.
- Go to menu `File > Invalidate Cache/Restart...`
- Remove JDK and install again. I'm using `JDK jdk-8u131-macosx-x64` downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- Delete all build folders and `Rebuild Project`
- Rollback to my project's stable source code that I built successfully in the past.
- Try to use Android Studio 3.0 Preview
- Downgrade or upgrade `Gradle Plugin`
- Download and replace the JDK bundle with Android studio [follow this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37121306)

All above methods didn't help to keep my Android Studio stability.

I am using Macbook with 16Gb of RAM, core i7, `MacOS Sierra 10.12.5` and I don't think the hang is regarding to my laptop specification,

So I report my situation here and hope someone can help to give me new recommendation. Any idea or suggestion are appreciated.

*Update*: I check the logs of Android Studio under `~/Library/Logs/Android Studio2.3/` and see some exception log files. Below is the latest one:

```
2017-07-04 19:14:35,633 [1233357]   INFO - roid.sdk.MessageBuildingSdkLog - Exception from KotlinOutputParser 
2017-07-04 19:14:35,633 [1233357]   INFO - roid.sdk.MessageBuildingSdkLog - com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.<init>(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList) 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.<init>(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper$simpleMessageConstructor$2.invoke(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:171)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper$simpleMessageConstructor$2.invoke(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:143)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.getSimpleMessageConstructor(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createNewMessage(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:272)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createMessage(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:250)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createMessage$default(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:244)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelperKt.parse(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParser.parse(KotlinOutputParser.java:28)
    at com.android.ide.common.blame.parser.ToolOutputParser.parseToolOutput(ToolOutputParser.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.output.parser.BuildOutputParser.parseGradleOutput(BuildOutputParser.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor$GradleTasksExecutorImpl.lambda$collectMessages$5(GradleTasksExecutor.java:516)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

*Update 2* Sometime Android Studio show a dialog for error report, with this message inside:

```
Cannot add jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar from plugin 'Kotlin' to external compiler classpath: home directory of plugin not found
```

Comment: I don't know if it's possible on Mac, but on Linux I can run Android Studio from console via startup scirpt `bin/studio.sh` and see error messages on console. Maybe try to do the same on you Mac, I think it should be possible to run program from command line in terminal. You should also look into logs (on Linux, they are located at `~/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/log` )

Comment: I can't start the AS as you said, but I found the idea log, see my update for the log, there are some exception log that I think they are problem of AS

Comment: This should not display that kind of popup messages I think, it just will cause Kotlin projects compilation errors, but I may be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can build and continue coding without crash ( at least after 1 hour I don't get crash).
For the Android Studio 2.3, I select `File > Power Save Mode` so it won't hang out any more. The worse thing is I can't use intelligent auto complete or auto-build at background.

Then, I install again `Android studio 3.0 Preview Canary 5`, using `Gradle tool 3.0.0 alpha5`. Fix all compile warnings (such as replace deprecated gradle functions by new ones), update all libraries to latest version,... It works!

Now I got 2 versions of Android Studio running concurrently. The old one running with Power Save Mode, the new one running with normal mode.

Comment: Did you resolve the NoSuchMethodException error? I have the same issue.

Comment: Yes I did, please try the steps I mentioned in the answer