# Rendering problems with Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, xml, rendering

I just updated Android Studio to 3.0 and I can't see my preview of the xml file..
It says

```
Exception raised during rendering: Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface
    at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.reset(Paint_Delegate.java:1244)
    at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.<init>(Paint_Delegate.java:1198)
    at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nInit(Paint_Delegate.java:694)
    at android.graphics.Paint.nInit(Paint.java)
    at android.graphics.Paint.<init>(Paint.java:481)
    at android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable.<init>(ColorDrawable.java:49)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:303)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:249)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:140)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:288)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:547)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and can't render it. 
pls help me :(

Comment: delete yourDirectory/.android Folder. Make Sure First Close you close android studio. after delete open it again.

Comment: @JJG I did it.. but still the same error :

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953441/android-studio-layout-preview-rendering-issue-after-update/47011783#47011783

Answer (score 2):

After update Android Studio up to 3.0 I had problems with showing layouts previews too. That's what helped me:

1. Go to menu "File"
2. Choose "Invalidate Cashes / Restart"
3. In opened window click "Invalidate and Restart"

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 2):

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\layoutlib\data\fonts

Replace the fonts.xml file with this and restart

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    WARNING: Parsing of this file by third-party apps is not supported. The
    file, and the font files it refers to, will be renamed and/or moved out
    from their respective location in the next Android release, and/or the
    format or syntax of the file may change significantly. You must not
    parse this file for information about system fonts. Instead, you must
    call android.text.FontManager#getSystemFonts(). For example, it can be
    called as context.getSystemService(FontManager.class).getSystemFonts().
    Note that the returned FontConfig includes data on all the defined font
    families and all the details about weight, style, etc. It also provides
    an open file descriptor to each font file. Note that callers of the API
    should ensure they close the given file descriptors once they are done
    using them.

    In this file, all fonts without names are added to the default list.
    Fonts are chosen based on a match: full BCP-47 language tag including
    script, then just language, and finally order (the first font containing
    the glyph).

    Order of appearance is also the tiebreaker for weight matching. This is
    the reason why the 900 weights of Roboto precede the 700 weights - we
    prefer the former when an 800 weight is requested. Since bold spans
    effectively add 300 to the weight, this ensures that 900 is the bold
    paired with the 500 weight, ensuring adequate contrast.
-->
<familyset version="22">
    <!-- first font is default -->
    <family name="sans-serif">
        <font weight="100" style="normal">Roboto-Thin.ttf</font>
        <font weight="100" style="italic">Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="normal">Roboto-Light.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="italic">Roboto-LightItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">Roboto-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="italic">Roboto-Italic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="500" style="normal">Roboto-Medium.ttf</font>
        <font weight="500" style="italic">Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="900" style="normal">Roboto-Black.ttf</font>
        <font weight="900" style="italic">Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">Roboto-Bold.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="italic">Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <!-- Note that aliases must come after the fonts they reference. -->
    <alias name="sans-serif-thin" to="sans-serif" weight="100" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-light" to="sans-serif" weight="300" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-medium" to="sans-serif" weight="500" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-black" to="sans-serif" weight="900" />
    <alias name="arial" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="helvetica" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="tahoma" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="verdana" to="sans-serif" />

    <family name="sans-serif-condensed">
        <font weight="300" style="normal">RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="italic">RobotoCondensed-LightItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="italic">RobotoCondensed-Italic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="italic">RobotoCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="sans-serif-condensed-light" to="sans-serif-condensed" weight="300" />

    <family name="serif">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSerif-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSerif-Bold.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="italic">NotoSerif-Italic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="italic">NotoSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="times" to="serif" />
    <alias name="times new roman" to="serif" />
    <alias name="palatino" to="serif" />
    <alias name="georgia" to="serif" />
    <alias name="baskerville" to="serif" />
    <alias name="goudy" to="serif" />
    <alias name="fantasy" to="serif" />
    <alias name="ITC Stone Serif" to="serif" />

    <family name="monospace">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">DroidSansMono.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="sans-serif-monospace" to="monospace" />
    <alias name="monaco" to="monospace" />

    <family name="serif-monospace">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">CutiveMono.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="courier" to="serif-monospace" />
    <alias name="courier new" to="serif-monospace" />

    <family name="casual">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">ComingSoon.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <family name="cursive">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">DancingScript-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">DancingScript-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <family name="sans-serif-smallcaps">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">CarroisGothicSC-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <!-- fallback fonts -->
    <family lang="und-Arab" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabic-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Arab" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabicUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabicUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Ethi">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansEthiopic-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansEthiopic-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Hebr">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansHebrew-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Thai" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansThai-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansThai-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Thai" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansThaiUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansThaiUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Armn">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansArmenian-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansArmenian-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <!-- TODO: add Geok -->
    <family lang="und-Geor">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGeorgian-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGeorgian-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Deva" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagari-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Deva" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagariUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagariUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <!-- All scripts of India should come after Devanagari, due to shared
         danda characters.
    -->
    <family lang="und-Gujr" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGujarati-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGujarati-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Gujr" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGujaratiUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGujaratiUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Guru" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhi-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhi-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Guru" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhiUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhiUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Taml" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTamil-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Taml" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTamilUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTamilUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mlym" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalam-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalam-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mlym" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalamUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalamUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Beng" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBengali-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansBengali-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Beng" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBengaliUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansBengaliUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Telu" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTelugu-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTelugu-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Telu" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTeluguUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTeluguUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Knda" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKannada-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKannada-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Knda" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKannadaUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKannadaUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Orya" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOriya-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansOriya-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Orya" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOriyaUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansOriyaUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <family lang="und-Sinh">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansSinhala-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Khmr" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKhmer-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKhmer-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Khmr" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKhmerUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKhmerUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Laoo" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLao-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansLao-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Laoo" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLaoUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansLaoUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mymr" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmar-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmar-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mymr" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmarUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmarUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Thaa">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansThaana-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansThaana-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Cham">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCham-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansCham-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Avst">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansAvestan-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Bali">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBalinese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Bamu">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBamum-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Batk">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBatak-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Brah">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBrahmi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Bugi">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBuginese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Buhd">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBuhid-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Cans">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCanadianAboriginal-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Cari">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCarian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Cher">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCherokee-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Copt">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCoptic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Xsux">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCuneiform-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Cprt">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCypriot-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Dsrt">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansDeseret-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Egyp">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansEgyptianHieroglyphs-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Glag">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGlagolitic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Goth">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGothic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Hano">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansHanunoo-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Armi">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansImperialAramaic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Phli">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansInscriptionalPahlavi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Prti">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansInscriptionalParthian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Java">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansJavanese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Kthi">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKaithi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Kali">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKayahLi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Khar">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKharoshthi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Lepc">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLepcha-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Limb">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLimbu-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Linb">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLinearB-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Lisu">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLisu-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Lyci">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLycian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Lydi">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLydian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mand">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMandaic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mtei">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMeeteiMayek-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Talu">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansNewTaiLue-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Nkoo">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansNKo-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Ogam">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOgham-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Olck">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOlChiki-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Ital">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOldItalic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Xpeo">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOldPersian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Sarb">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOldSouthArabian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Orkh">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOldTurkic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Osma">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOsmanya-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Phag">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansPhagsPa-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Phnx">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansPhoenician-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Rjng">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansRejang-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Runr">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansRunic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Samr">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSamaritan-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Saur">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSaurashtra-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Shaw">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansShavian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Sund">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSundanese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Sylo">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSylotiNagri-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <!-- Esrangela should precede Eastern and Western Syriac, since it's our default form. -->
    <family lang="und-Syre">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSyriacEstrangela-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Syrn">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSyriacEastern-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Syrj">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSyriacWestern-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Tglg">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTagalog-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Tagb">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTagbanwa-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Lana">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTaiTham-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Tavt">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTaiViet-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Tibt">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTibetan-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTibetan-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Tfng">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTifinagh-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Ugar">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansUgaritic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Vaii">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansVai-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Yiii">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansYi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSymbols-Regular-Subsetted.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="zh-Hans">
        <font weight="400" style="normal" index="2">NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc</font>
    </family>
    <!-- TODO: Add Bopo -->
    <family lang="zh-Hant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal" index="3">NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="ja">
        <font weight="400" style="normal" index="0">NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="ko">
        <font weight="400" style="normal" index="1">NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Zsye">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoColorEmoji.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Zsym">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSymbols-Regular-Subsetted2.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <!--
        Tai Le and Mongolian are intentionally kept last, to make sure they don't override
        the East Asian punctuation for Chinese.
    -->
    <family lang="und-Tale">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTaiLe-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mong">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMongolian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
</familyset>
```

Answer (score 1):

same problem to me.

have you ever edited fonts.xml before, (maybe korean fonts or something edited)

1. open "\plugins\android\lib\layoutlib\data\fonts\fonts.xml" file
2. in my case, 474~475 line was corrupted.
   you must fix

   ```
   '<family lan' to '</familyset>'
   ```

or reinstall android studio 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me, I feel like it is an Android Studio bug? I had to change the app theme to use `Base.Theme.AppCompat` instead of just `Theme.AppCompat`.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

After this the xml layouts render fine.

One problem that stemmed from this solution is that I could not use a parent theme with NoActionBar, so I had to hide it manually if using a Toolbar:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suffered same problem with same rendering error message.

After many hours of research and tried this and that.. and I ended up reinstalling Android Studio 3.0 after I completely uninstalled following this guideline : [How to completely uninstall Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio#answer-18458893)

and the result? it works well :)

Answer (score 0):

I also have an issue of previewing xml layout. but now it fixed.

Because you may have updated any file on your Android Studio installed directory.

My condition I updated font.xml file for previewing Korean character purpose `(Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\layoutlib\data\fonts\fonts.xml)`.

And Android Studio 3.0 has made an update on that file for previewing Korean character, so after installing I don't need to update my font.xml anymore.

My solution are very simple steps:

- Uninstall the current installed Android Studio 3.0
- Download and install the latest version of Android Studio 3.0 again.

After uninstalling everything in the installed directory will be removed and the fully update of Android Studio 3.0 when you install the download file.

Check my comment here for detail: [Android Studio layout preview rendering issue after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953441/android-studio-layout-preview-rendering-issue-after-update)

hope my solution help you.