# Android Studio layout preview rendering issue after update

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am so confused. It worked fine just before the most recent update to Android Studio 3.0.

All of my xml files have the same rendering issue. I cannot see anything.

It says:

" Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface

Exception raised during rendering: Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface

Tip: Try to refresh the layout. "

No matter how many times I try to refresh this thing, it just won't work.
I restarted Android Studio, but it still won't work.

I have no idea where to even start with fixing this problem, because I've never seen such problem before. I googled it, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

I need help. Please save me!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636393/parsesdkcontent-failed-could-not-initialize-class-android-graphics-typeface

Comment: I tried the solution, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\layoutlib\data\fonts

Replace the fonts.xml file with this and restart

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    WARNING: Parsing of this file by third-party apps is not supported. The
    file, and the font files it refers to, will be renamed and/or moved out
    from their respective location in the next Android release, and/or the
    format or syntax of the file may change significantly. You must not
    parse this file for information about system fonts. Instead, you must
    call android.text.FontManager#getSystemFonts(). For example, it can be
    called as context.getSystemService(FontManager.class).getSystemFonts().
    Note that the returned FontConfig includes data on all the defined font
    families and all the details about weight, style, etc. It also provides
    an open file descriptor to each font file. Note that callers of the API
    should ensure they close the given file descriptors once they are done
    using them.

    In this file, all fonts without names are added to the default list.
    Fonts are chosen based on a match: full BCP-47 language tag including
    script, then just language, and finally order (the first font containing
    the glyph).

    Order of appearance is also the tiebreaker for weight matching. This is
    the reason why the 900 weights of Roboto precede the 700 weights - we
    prefer the former when an 800 weight is requested. Since bold spans
    effectively add 300 to the weight, this ensures that 900 is the bold
    paired with the 500 weight, ensuring adequate contrast.
-->
<familyset version="22">
    <!-- first font is default -->
    <family name="sans-serif">
        <font weight="100" style="normal">Roboto-Thin.ttf</font>
        <font weight="100" style="italic">Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="normal">Roboto-Light.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="italic">Roboto-LightItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">Roboto-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="italic">Roboto-Italic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="500" style="normal">Roboto-Medium.ttf</font>
        <font weight="500" style="italic">Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="900" style="normal">Roboto-Black.ttf</font>
        <font weight="900" style="italic">Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">Roboto-Bold.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="italic">Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <!-- Note that aliases must come after the fonts they reference. -->
    <alias name="sans-serif-thin" to="sans-serif" weight="100" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-light" to="sans-serif" weight="300" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-medium" to="sans-serif" weight="500" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-black" to="sans-serif" weight="900" />
    <alias name="arial" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="helvetica" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="tahoma" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="verdana" to="sans-serif" />

    <family name="sans-serif-condensed">
        <font weight="300" style="normal">RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="italic">RobotoCondensed-LightItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="italic">RobotoCondensed-Italic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="italic">RobotoCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="sans-serif-condensed-light" to="sans-serif-condensed" weight="300" />

    <family name="serif">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSerif-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSerif-Bold.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="italic">NotoSerif-Italic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="italic">NotoSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="times" to="serif" />
    <alias name="times new roman" to="serif" />
    <alias name="palatino" to="serif" />
    <alias name="georgia" to="serif" />
    <alias name="baskerville" to="serif" />
    <alias name="goudy" to="serif" />
    <alias name="fantasy" to="serif" />
    <alias name="ITC Stone Serif" to="serif" />

    <family name="monospace">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">DroidSansMono.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="sans-serif-monospace" to="monospace" />
    <alias name="monaco" to="monospace" />

    <family name="serif-monospace">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">CutiveMono.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <alias name="courier" to="serif-monospace" />
    <alias name="courier new" to="serif-monospace" />

    <family name="casual">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">ComingSoon.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <family name="cursive">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">DancingScript-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">DancingScript-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <family name="sans-serif-smallcaps">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">CarroisGothicSC-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <!-- fallback fonts -->
    <family lang="und-Arab" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabic-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Arab" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabicUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoNaskhArabicUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Ethi">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansEthiopic-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansEthiopic-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Hebr">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansHebrew-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Thai" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansThai-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansThai-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Thai" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansThaiUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansThaiUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Armn">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansArmenian-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansArmenian-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <!-- TODO: add Geok -->
    <family lang="und-Geor">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGeorgian-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGeorgian-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Deva" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagari-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Deva" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagariUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansDevanagariUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <!-- All scripts of India should come after Devanagari, due to shared
         danda characters.
    -->
    <family lang="und-Gujr" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGujarati-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGujarati-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Gujr" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGujaratiUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGujaratiUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Guru" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhi-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhi-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Guru" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhiUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansGurmukhiUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Taml" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTamil-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Taml" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTamilUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTamilUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mlym" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalam-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalam-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mlym" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalamUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMalayalamUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Beng" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBengali-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansBengali-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Beng" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBengaliUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansBengaliUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Telu" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTelugu-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTelugu-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Telu" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTeluguUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTeluguUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Knda" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKannada-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKannada-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Knda" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKannadaUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKannadaUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Orya" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOriya-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansOriya-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Orya" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOriyaUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansOriyaUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>

    <family lang="und-Sinh">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansSinhala-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Khmr" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKhmer-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKhmer-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Khmr" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKhmerUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansKhmerUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Laoo" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLao-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansLao-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Laoo" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLaoUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansLaoUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mymr" variant="elegant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmar-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmar-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mymr" variant="compact">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmarUI-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansMyanmarUI-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Thaa">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansThaana-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansThaana-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Cham">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCham-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansCham-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Avst">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansAvestan-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Bali">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBalinese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Bamu">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBamum-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Batk">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBatak-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Brah">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBrahmi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Bugi">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBuginese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Buhd">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansBuhid-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Cans">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCanadianAboriginal-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Cari">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCarian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Cher">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCherokee-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Copt">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCoptic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Xsux">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCuneiform-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Cprt">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansCypriot-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Dsrt">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansDeseret-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Egyp">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansEgyptianHieroglyphs-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Glag">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGlagolitic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Goth">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansGothic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Hano">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansHanunoo-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Armi">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansImperialAramaic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Phli">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansInscriptionalPahlavi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Prti">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansInscriptionalParthian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Java">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansJavanese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Kthi">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKaithi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Kali">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKayahLi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Khar">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansKharoshthi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Lepc">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLepcha-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Limb">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLimbu-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Linb">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLinearB-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Lisu">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLisu-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Lyci">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLycian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Lydi">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansLydian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mand">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMandaic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mtei">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMeeteiMayek-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Talu">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansNewTaiLue-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Nkoo">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansNKo-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Ogam">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOgham-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Olck">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOlChiki-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Ital">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOldItalic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Xpeo">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOldPersian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Sarb">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOldSouthArabian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Orkh">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOldTurkic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Osma">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansOsmanya-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Phag">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansPhagsPa-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Phnx">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansPhoenician-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Rjng">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansRejang-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Runr">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansRunic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Samr">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSamaritan-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Saur">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSaurashtra-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Shaw">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansShavian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Sund">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSundanese-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Sylo">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSylotiNagri-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <!-- Esrangela should precede Eastern and Western Syriac, since it's our default form. -->
    <family lang="und-Syre">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSyriacEstrangela-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Syrn">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSyriacEastern-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Syrj">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSyriacWestern-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Tglg">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTagalog-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Tagb">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTagbanwa-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Lana">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTaiTham-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Tavt">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTaiViet-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Tibt">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTibetan-Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">NotoSansTibetan-Bold.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Tfng">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTifinagh-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Ugar">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansUgaritic-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Vaii">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansVai-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Yiii">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansYi-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSymbols-Regular-Subsetted.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="zh-Hans">
        <font weight="400" style="normal" index="2">NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc</font>
    </family>
    <!-- TODO: Add Bopo -->
    <family lang="zh-Hant">
        <font weight="400" style="normal" index="3">NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="ja">
        <font weight="400" style="normal" index="0">NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="ko">
        <font weight="400" style="normal" index="1">NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Zsye">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoColorEmoji.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Zsym">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansSymbols-Regular-Subsetted2.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <!--
        Tai Le and Mongolian are intentionally kept last, to make sure they don't override
        the East Asian punctuation for Chinese.
    -->
    <family lang="und-Tale">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansTaiLe-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family lang="und-Mong">
        <font weight="400" style="normal">NotoSansMongolian-Regular.ttf</font>
    </family>
</familyset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by selecting another version of Sdk to show the layout preview as shown in `screenshot`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I've Googled for the topic everywhere but I can't find any solution. I can't preview my layout.xml, but now it got fixed. I don't know whether my solution will work for you and I don't understand how that can be worked.

First, I use Android Studio version 2.3 and it works fine. I also edited my font.xml located in Android Studio installed directory (Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\layoutlib\data\fonts\fonts.xml) for previewing Korean character purposes. Then when I see the release info about the new latest Android Studio 3.0, I check for update and install the new update of the latest version.

I've got a dialog appeared during the update because I've edited the font.xml for previewing Korean character purpose when designing layout.xml.

The dialog is about there is a conflict on font.xml so the update will not override the file. I think the error might because of the new release of Android Studio 3.0 has fixed the issue for previewing Korean characters and other characters that cause the error "Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface".

Here is my solution is to:

- Simply uninstall the current Android Studio of 3.0
- Download and install the latest version of Android Studio of 3.0 again

Uninstalling the current version means everything located in the Android Studio directory will be remove including the font.xml.

The fully new update of 3.0 is when you download and install again.

Hope my simple solution will help.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that it needs font file on your PC for the file fonts.xml.

In my case, I have a font; NotoSansCJKkr-Regular which is using on my pc in Windows fonts folder, I have changed the file fonts.xml to put this font.
Because original fonts.xml file doesn't have the name of the font.
So that I needed to add the font.