# Unable to run / open Android Studio app and android emulator in Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio-3.0

I have already tried deleting the config file and reinstall android studio. I still have problem in opening / running the ide. I tried to run it as administrator, using the terminal:

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/
sudo ./studio
```

I've managed to open it. But unable to run it on emulator or anything. I've manage to open the sdk tool though. But when i try to run the emulator, this is what i get:

```
9:36 AM Emulator: WARNING: Unknown AVD name [7.0_API_22], use -list-avds to see valid list.

9:36 AM Emulator: HOME is defined but there is no file 7.0_API_22.ini in $HOME/.android/avd

9:36 AM Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

9:36 AM Emulator: WARNING: Unknown AVD name [7.0_API_22], use -list-avds to see valid list.

9:36 AM Emulator: HOME is defined but there is no file 7.0_API_22.ini in $HOME/.android/avd

9:36 AM Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

9:36 AM Emulator: WARNING: Unknown AVD name [7.0_API_22], use -list-avds to see valid list.

9:36 AM Emulator: HOME is defined but there is no file 7.0_API_22.ini in $HOME/.android/avd

9:36 AM Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

9:36 AM Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

9:36 AM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me. I have used it before, and I can open it easily and run it without the need on using the terminal each time i tried to open it. I can even open the emulator. FYI, I'm using **mac OSX version 10.11.6**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally have it running. I did as [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458893/8944114) said. I **removed all the android files, component** inside mac. Then I re-install it again.
During installation, I picked custom installation as it detected I have a previous android sdk, avd files. Delete the files associated with it.

I have to install the sdk, avd again... but at least I got it running without having to call terminal each time I open android studio. Might not be the best solutions, (since I have to reinstall everything again) but it will do.

Answer (score 0):

Do the files the logs say are missing actually exist on your disk?

file 7.0_API_22.ini in $HOME/.android/avd

Comment: it actually missing

Comment: What does the output for  this say: use -list-avds to see valid list