# macOS "The application Android Studio can't be opened"

Tags: android, android-studio, macos-high-sierra

I am getting the error "The application Android Studio can't be opened" after updating my MacBook Pro to latest version 10.13.4 I am using Android Studio 3.1 I can open all the applications on my Mac except for Android Studio. I have searched on internet and couldn't find any related answer for this problem. Please help?

Comment: Did you upgraded *JDK* to latest version as well ?

Answer (score 13):

I've just fixed it by removing the `studio.vmoptions` file.

```
> rm /Users/{user}/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.2/studio.vmoptions
```

Comment: I was getting the same error in AppCode and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue and it seemed to be caused by comments in my studio.vmoptions file

~/Library/Preferences/.AndroidStudioX.X/studio.vmoptions

Once I removed the comments, I was able to open Android Studio again.

Comment: I was unable to launch Android Studio on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (app icon bounces about 6 to 7 times, then disappears). This finally fixed it. I also deleted any other installed AndroidStudio folders within `~/Library/Preferences/` that I wasn't using. Thanks so much!

Comment: delete ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had to do:

```
sudo chmod 644 /Applications/Android\Studio\Preview.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

because it had
`-rw-------` permissions instead of `-rw-r--r--@`

Comment: That solved my problem. I had Android Studio installed by another admin user and with my current user it wouldn't open.

Comment: For some reason, my VirtualBox will not able to start any VM once a while.  Running `sudo chown -R root:wheel /Applications` will solve it.  But this seems has cause problem in Android Studio.  Now another `chmod` command to solve another problem. Thanks.

Comment: Of all the above this worked for me for

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue, which I solved by below *steps* :

1. Delete *Android Studio* completely from your mac
2. Install through the *command* :

   ```
   brew install --cask android-studio
   ```

Comment: This method worked for me. I installed from downloading the dmg from the google website and had no existing preferences to delete. I much prefer having this tracked in brew with everything else.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is facing this issue, locate your Android Studio configuration files.

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio<Version>
```

In my case, maximum heap size set by default was 20MB, which was too low. I was getting the same above error for Android Studio Preview.
I modified it to 256MB, Android Studio Preview started normally.

To change maximum heap size, go to the configuration file -> `studio.vmoptions`

Example: from `-Xmx20m` to `-Xmx256m`

increase the heap size to higher value.

> The studio.vmoptions file allows you to customize options for Android
> Studio's JVM. To improve Studio's performance, the most common option
> to adjust is the maximum heap size.

For more [details](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config)

Note: Once Android Studio opens up, it might ask you to increase the heap size again.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** :- if you are facing this error ***“The application Android Studio can't be opened”*** or ***LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Android Studio.app.***

Then try

**Go To Applications -> Tap on **Android Studio -> Show Package Contents -> Contents**

Now **copy** the jdk version from **jre -> jdk -> contents ->open info.plist -> copy Bundle version's value**

then come **back to main Contents Folder** ( Android Studio -> Show Package Contents -> Contents ) and open **info.plist -> JVMOptions -> JVMVersion and add/paste in its value** and save and exit.

Now, You will be **able to open Android Studio.** :)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem like you.
there is something wrong with my home directory.
it has been fixed.

```
sudo mkdir /Users/XXX/.android
sudo chown -R XXX:staff /Users/XXX/.android
```

good luck for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command: `sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`
(sudo is important required)

After try some suggest but not help

```
- trying different versions (even beta or canary) from official and none-official sources
- updating, uninstalling and reinstalling the app
- trying jetbrain toolbox for installation
- updating jdk to latest version (19)
- changing configs in .vmoptions file or removing it (including-Dsun.font.layoutengine=icu)
- removing gradle,android sdk and etc folders related to android studio
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Android completely and open it again

Follow this answer to know more about complete android studio removal for MAC

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46960087/10239870