# Unable to open Android Studio in with other users mac m1 big sur

Tags: macos, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio, and it works as it should, but when I switch to another user account on my Mac i get this message.

> You can’t open the application “Android Studio” because it may be damaged or incomplete.

Is it possible to use the app in several accounts? I have tried saving the SDK in the Share folder, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610620/macos-the-application-android-studio-cant-be-opened

someone has this error please check that!

Comment: Thank you Buddhika i have tried the permission solution and it have worked