# How to fix 'Unable to establish a connection to adb'?

Tags: macos, android-studio, adb

I am facing a problem which my Android Studio is unable to establish a connection to adb. The problem seems occur after I updated my Android Studio from 3.1.1 to 3.1.2 on my Mac (macOS High Sierra 10.13.1).

[image]

I tried to updated the Android Studio to 3.1.3, Android SDK Platform-Tools to 28.0.0, macOS to High Sierra 10.13.5, but the problem still exists. I also filed a bug on Android.com about 2 months ago, but I got no response.

Anyone could recommend how to fix?

Comment: Same problem here. But sometimes Android Studio show me a different kind of dialog. Telling that it can't connect with ADB, asking me if I want to cancel or retry to connect.

A workaround is to downgrade to the 3.0.0 version. I've tried all other versions above it, but they all have the same problem. Here you can find older versions of Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.

To remove completely Android Studio, check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio.

Comment: Same error here. Do you find any solution? My Android studio version 3.3.2. Mac 10.14.1.