# project Root project "Gradle project not found for Module: "MyApplication"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

My new `Android studio` version is giving below error for the sample project could you please help?

Below is the logs for IDE Fatal Error i got

[IDE Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAI5G.jpg)

```
Root project path of the Gradle project not found for Module: 'MyApplication2'
com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger$EmptyThrowable
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:140)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.GradleOrderEnumeratorHandler.addCustomModuleRoots(GradleOrderEnumeratorHandler.java:110)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleOrderEnumeratorHandlerFactory$1.addCustomModuleRoots(AndroidGradleOrderEnumeratorHandlerFactory.java:93)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.OrderEnumeratorBase.addCustomRootsForModule(OrderEnumeratorBase.java:422)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.OrderRootsEnumeratorImpl.collectModuleRoots(OrderRootsEnumeratorImpl.java:238)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.OrderRootsEnumeratorImpl.lambda$computeRoots$0(OrderRootsEnumeratorImpl.java:108)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.OrderEnumeratorBase.processEntries(OrderEnumeratorBase.java:303)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ModuleOrderEnumerator.forEach(ModuleOrderEnumerator.java:47)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.OrderRootsEnumeratorImpl.computeRoots(OrderRootsEnumeratorImpl.java:104)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.OrderRootsEnumeratorImpl.getRoots(OrderRootsEnumeratorImpl.java:74)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.OrderEnumerator.getClassesRoots(OrderEnumerator.java:159)
```

Because of this error Gradle build is getting failed  [Gradle error screen shot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLuTn.jpg)

Also in Project structure required files are not getting generated

for example: Application specific `build.gradle` [Project structure picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Ivv.jpg)

**PS: Android studio version is 3.1.4**

Comment: same problem here. Still debugging...

Comment: @JayBKim Thank you. Please let me know if you find any clue

Comment: I too got the same exception!  Please share, if any any solution or work around has been found!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by below methods.

I don't know what OS you are running, but mine is macOS High Sierra, and

Android Studio version is same as yours. (v 3.1.4)

#### First thing I tried, and it worked.

I changed the gradle version to 4.2 and re-opened the project.

> File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Gradle version from 4.4 to 4.2

#### I changed the gradle version from 4.2 to 4.4 again.

I closed the project and re-opened it after I deleted the gradle on the below directory.

> /Users/$USERNAME/.gradle/wrapper/dists/GRADLE_VERSION

Comment: B Kim I tried your suggestion and I still don't see the build.gradle app file  getting generated . Could you please help

Comment: @user2454202 What OS are you running? Have you tried [completely uninstall Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio) and reinstall it? If you haven't, I suggest you to do it first. If it doesn't work, we can start going from there.