# Android Emulator not starting - Application not responding

Tags: android, android-emulator

My emulator suddenly stopped working. There were no updates made on my OS, Android Studio, emulator, or otherwise. (Using MacOS) Normally when I try to run my emulator I see the emulator icon in my doc and the device window shows promptly. However, when I try to run now, I get the bouncing blue folder in my dock titled "Emulator". After a few minutes, it stops bouncing and appears to just be a folder. Clicking on it does nothing. Right clicking on it, I have the option to force quit. If I open "Force Quit Applications", I find "qemu-system-x86 (not responding)" listed. There is no emulator window found.

Things I have tried

- Restarting everything. OS, Android studio.
- Deleting the emulator and creating new one.
- Trying different emulator images.
- Trying different emulator frames.
- Uninstalling/installing HAXM.
- Uninstalling/installing emulator.
- Uninstalling/installing images.
- Normally I run the emulator via Android Studio. For this issue I tried running emulator by command with `-verbose` in hopes of finding any clues. This is the output:

```
emulator: Android emulator version 28.0.23.0 (build_id 5264690) (CL:be2be19ca0131957449e8c0ded5e55070f9537b0)
emulator: Found AVD name 'Pixel_2_Pie'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator: argv[0]: './emulator'; program directory: '/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/.'
emulator:  Found directory: /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator: Probing for /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
emulator: Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (based on configuration)
emulator:  Found directory: /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator: emuDirName: '/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator: Probing for /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
emulator: try dir /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/.
emulator: Trying emulator path '/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64'
emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/gles_angle'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
emulator: Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
emulator: Running :/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "Pixel_2_Pie"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -avd Pixel_2_Pie -verbose
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: using snapshot lock path: /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.avd/snapshot.lock
emulator: using multi-instance lock path: /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.avd/multiinstance.lock
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 28
emulator: Read property file at /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: found skin 'pixel_2' in directory: /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/skins/
emulator: autoconfig: -skin pixel_2
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/skins/
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu-64
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img
emulator: Using initial vendor image: /Users/cbingham/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//vendor.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1536MB

emulator: VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 384MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 2 DNS servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

And this is the details of the emulator from above:

```
Name: Pixel_2_Pie
CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)
Path: /Users/cbingham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_Pie.avd
Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 28)
Skin: pixel_2
SD Card: 512M
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: pixel_2
hw.lcd.width: 1080
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 28
tag.id: google_apis_playstore
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.camera.front: emulated
avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 2 Pie
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.ramSize: 1536
PlayStore.enabled: true
fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
hw.cpu.ncore: 4
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.dPad: no
hw.lcd.height: 1920
vm.heapSize: 256
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86/
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: virtualscene
AvdId: Pixel_2_Pie
hw.lcd.density: 420
hw.arc: false
hw.device.hash2: MD5:55acbc83578326788df66a5cEd4c9aa
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google Play
runtime.network.latency: none
disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the disk.dataPartition.size is sometimes set to "6442450944" which equals to 6TB (if using kilobytes). When I set disk.dataPartition.size back to **800M** the emulator starts without problems. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac 7.8 Preview and it occurs sporadic with almost all my emulators.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and tried everything that I can, but nothing worked other than uninstalling Android Studio.

It may be pain in the ass to reset everything, but I would advise you to just uninstall & remove **everything** related to AndroidStudio, then just re-install it.

[uninstall instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)