# Why do I get Gradle Sync Issues Host is down in Android Studio 3.5.1 on mac

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded Android Studio and SDKs about 6 months ago to build to android in Unity. When I've tried to use Android Studio I get error: Gradle sync issues: Host is down. I've googled but can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem atleast not since 2 years ago. Nobody in my class has this issue either.

I unistalled all files related to gradle and Android with the terminal using the answer in this thread:

[How to completely uninstall Android Studio on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)

I then installed it fresh with standard settings but I still get this error. Why do I get this?

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrVdi.png)

PS. I haven't posted any screenshots because I don't know what is needed. If you need it, I'll be happy to post what is necessary.

Comment: Are you using for build new project or build unity application?

Comment: maybe consider posting any gradle logs or errors you see, this could be useful for people trying to help you out. please post these as text instead of images, as it just makes life easier for everyone :D

Comment: Added a screenshot. This is when I try to create a new project in Android Studio, in Unity it works to build. There is a very long list of errors. The exceptions are: LocationAwareException, HttpHostConnectException, ConnectException, ProjectConfigurationException.