# In Flutter Project Android project screen is automatically opening

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

When I am trying to open my flutter project in Android Studio

[image]

**Android Project** screen is automatically opened with blank screen and when i a rebuild project it will automatically increasing with same project/blank screen

Comment: have you installed dart and flutter plugins ?

Comment: yep i already installed flutter plugins

Comment: and if you try building a new project with android studio do you still get  black screen

Comment: yes whenever i open new or recent project of flutters i get same screen and when i close this screen android studio is stuck

Comment: try uninstalling android studio or using vs code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a alternative solution!

Just delete the .androidstudio from your user folder and create it all again (you need to install all plugins and configs again)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and I solved it by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac) and installing from scratch android studio, of course do not delete your folder with the projects.

Answer (score 0):

copy installed plugins from

Goto ***C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio\config***
move plugins folder somewhere

then delete .AndroidStudio folder

Start Android Studio 
**do not import your** 
after Android Studio Start close it

then paste your plugins folder to

**C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio\config**

Start Android Studio and use :)