# Android Emulator (AVD) fails to launch on macOS 10.15.4

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have a Macbook Pro from 2017 running macOS 10.15.4. I've had problems launching any Android emulator through the AVD manager or command line for the last two weeks. When I launch one either way, a folder icon appears in the dock, bounces for a minute or so, and then just stays there. No window appears for the emulator, and I don't get an error in the terminal output (when I launch through command line).

Fixes I've tried, after searching here and elsewhere:

1. Delete all virtual devices, restart machine, recreate and launch virtual device.
2. Delete all virtual devices, uninstall HAXM, restart machine, reinstall HAXM, recreate and launch virtual device.
3. Fully uninstall Android Studio, SDK, tools, etc (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)), reinstall, recreate and launch virtual device.
4. Force software graphics emulation, force hardware emulation (rather than automatic)
5. Use different Android versions (tried 26 through 29)

The next step I'm considering is a complete OS wipe, so I'm hoping someone can help me avoid that.

This is the terminal output, by the way:

```
joewilliams$ ./emulator @Pixel_C_API_29 -verbose
emulator: Android emulator version 30.0.5.0 (build_id 6306047) (CL:N/A)
emulator: Found AVD name 'Pixel_C_API_29'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator: argv[0]: './emulator'; program directory: '/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/.'
emulator:  Found directory: /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86/

emulator: emuDirName: '/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86/

emulator: Probing for /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
emulator: try dir /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/.
emulator: Trying emulator path '/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64'
emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/gles_angle'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Silencing all qWarning(); use qCWarning(...) instead: QT_LOGGING_RULES=default.warning=false
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
emulator: Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D: QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
emulator: Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
emulator: Running :/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "@Pixel_C_API_29"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/./qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 @Pixel_C_API_29 -verbose
emulator: autoconfig: -skin pixel_c
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/skins/
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu-64
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86//system.img
emulator: Using initial vendor image: /Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86//vendor.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /Users/joewilliams/.android/avd/Pixel_C_API_29.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Users/joewilliams/.android/avd/Pixel_C_API_29.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Users/joewilliams/.android/avd/Pixel_C_API_29.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /Users/joewilliams/.android/avd/Pixel_C_API_29.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
emulator: VM heap size 192MB is below hardware specified minimum of 512MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 4 DNS servers: 10.128.1.81 10.128.1.82 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76
emulator: trying to load skin file '/Users/joewilliams/Library/Android/sdk/skins//pixel_c/layout'
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.cmdline' = 'androidboot.logcat=v:* androidboot.consolepipe=qemu_pipe,pipe:logcat'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.logcat' = 'start'
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAXM version 7.5.1 (4) is installed and usable.
```

Edit: Forgot to mention, I don't have Docker installed. I saw from some older similar issues to this that Docker might cause conflicts or something, but it's not a problem here.

Edit 2: It turns out it was caused by relying solely on the display through my KVM. I have a StarTech KVM connected via Thunderbolt, which displays to two external monitors. When the Macbook is closed, the Android virtual device won't start. However, if it's open and the Macbook's screen is also displaying, then it works. Super weird.