# Emulator does not start (c066d201: unhandled exit 1d)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After I deleted some old AVDs and creating a new one, I cant get any AVD to start. If I start them through Android-Studio, the AVD window will launch but the screen stays black and Android-Studio stops responding. If I start the AVD through the command line with the following command:

```
./emulator @Pixel_3_Api_19
```

The behaviour is the same and I get the following output in the console:

```
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
emulator: WARNING: Running on a system with less than 6 logical cores. Setting number of virtual cores to 1
emulator: WARNING: EmulatorAdvertisement.cpp:80: Overwriting existing discovery file: /Users/koljenka/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/avd/running/pid_2730.ini
c066d201: unhandled exit 1d
c066d201: unhandled exit 1d
c066d201: unhandled exit 1d
c066d201: unhandled exit 1d
```

The `c066d201: unhandled exit 1d` line is printed constantly.

I'm running a 2017 MacBook Pro with MacOS Big Sur Dev Beta, but i had the emulator running fine on the dev beta before deleting the old AVDs.

Comment: I am on Big Sur latest beta and also having this issue. Its intermittent. I have had to delete the emulator and recreate it a few times. Same issue with Android Studio 4.1 beta

Comment: Thanks thats good to know. Maybe I'll just return back to Catalina for the time being.

Comment: This other question is linked with Google Issue Tracker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576252/android-emulators-are-not-working-on-osx-big-sur . I'm linking for someone in the future

Comment: I think this question is duplicate of well described: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576252/android-emulators-are-not-working-on-osx-big-sur

Comment: It's the other way around, your question is a duplicate of mine, as mine is a month older. But I think it's fine.

Comment: I updated macOS Big Sur to 11.0 (Beta) and the emulator is just working. Can someone else check it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use option -gpu host.

You run emulator correctly like this

~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -gpu host -avd Pixel_2_API_30

or try this:

create a file named advancedFeatures.ini in ~/.android

Put following settings in it:

Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on

Comment: Sadly, this didn't change anything.

Comment: @Koljenka Working for me with Big Sur beta 2, Android Studio 4.0.1 and emulator 30.0.12

Comment: @Koljenka You can also try create a file named advancedFeatures.ini in ~/.android. Put content like this: Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on

Comment: Both solutions proved useful. When the .ini file no longer worked the terminal command did.

Comment: Make sure to do `chmod 755 ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini`, otherwise you'll get the same error

Comment: hi the solution partially works for me.. It works if i try to run the command couple of times. Then if i close the emulator and try again it kept giving me unhandled exit 1d. Anyone had similar experience or know how to resolve this? Any help is much appreciated. thanks in advance..

Comment: @Adi got the same issue, I will try the canary preview, If I didn't answer then it hasn't worked

Comment: @Adi You can try remove and then add -gpu option to make it work, or reset emulator data.

Comment: @smoothdvd launching once without the -gpu host option and then turning it back on again worked for me! Thanks alot!

Comment: @smoothdvd i have tried removing and creating new ones, cold boot.. none of them helped..

Comment: thanks it works, but what is the difference with running the emulator on this mode?

Comment: This makes emulator slow and laggy

Comment: The upper solution is verified and is NOT working on OSX Big Sur

Comment: @Duna It works for me with macOS Big Sur from beta 3 to 6.

Comment: I'm on Big Sur beta 5 and I had to first create advancedFeatures.ini with options mentioned above and then start avd with -gpu host option

Answer (score 3):

Using Mac OS 11 Beta 6 (20A5364e) here.
None of the solutions I found worked until I've tried this:

1. Completely wipeout and reinstall Android Studio (not sure if this is necessary, try skipping this step first. Use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458893/5164932) as a guide)
2. Create your virtual device (if haven't already).
3. Now instead of running your device normally, open AVD manager and click **Cold Boot Now**:
   [image: Cold Boot Now option]
4. You will see a warning message, just click **DISMISS** and your device will start booting:
   [image: emulation engine failed message]

Comment: This always works or does the process have to be done every time I launch the emulator?

Comment: I do the cold boot thing everytime I need to turn on the emulator. it works that way for me every time.