# Android Studio hang when starting emulator

Tags: android-emulator

Android emulator can not boot and also
Android Studio is hanged when starting emulator.
My OSX version is Big Sur 11.0 Beta and Android Studio version 4.0.1.
Does anyone have experience in?

Comment: See the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148352/emulator-does-not-start-c066d201-unhandled-exit-1d