# Android Studio emulator hangs when installing on device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Emulator runs fine from a cold boot.  However, when I try to run my app with changes applied it hangs at install. When stuck installing the job will not timeout or cancel until I terminate the emulator.

[image: Stuck installing]

The work around has been to close out of the emulator and boot it again to run the new code.  This eats up a lot of time, I am hoping to figure out this issue so I am apply changes and rerun the normal way.

Here are the things I have tried:

- invalidating caches / restart
- Wipe Data
- Starting from Cold Boot
- creating a new emulator
- [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148352/emulator-does-not-start-c066d201-unhandled-exit-1d)

****Version info****

macOS Big Sur v11.2.1

Android studio 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I updated my operating system to `macOS Big Sur v11.4` which seems to have resolve the issue I was having.