# Android Studio updated, cannot start now, internal error thrown

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

I just updated to Android Studio 4.1 and upon startup the following issue is being thrown:

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.picocontainer.PicoRegistrationException: Key io.flutter.settings.FlutterSettings duplicated
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:618)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:628)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:1996)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.registerAppComponents(ApplicationLoader.kt:91)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.executeInitAppInEdt(ApplicationLoader.kt:63)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.access$executeInitAppInEdt(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$1$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:355)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.picocontainer.PicoRegistrationException: Key io.flutter.settings.FlutterSettings duplicated
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.registerComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:119)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:320)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:186)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:157)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$registerAppComponents$1.apply(ApplicationLoader.kt:93)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$registerAppComponents$1.apply(ApplicationLoader.kt)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    ... 20 more

-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64 by JetBrains s.r.o
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

I've followed the advice here to completely uninstall Android Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458893/471713 and on clean install it's still throwing the error.  Is there anywhere else I should look? I have other Jetbrains applications installed, so I'm not sure if there is some sort of conflict with another app?

Answer (score 7):

### FOR WINDOW 10

My problem is gone after this solution  Try may be the solution for your problem too

Run following command in Command Prompt as administrator

```
 netsh winsock reset
```

Restart your machine

I found the solution here  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmWUrFIK8RY

Comment: THIS ☝️ The only solution that worked for me.

Comment: it says restart your machine, but that wasn't necessary for me

Comment: I am also faced same issue and I tried the above solution but still facing the same issue.   If you had any other solution please share us. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on MacOS. Deleting the marketplace directory which contains plugins resolved the issue for me.

```
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.0/marketplace/
```

Comment: I had this problem with Android Studio 4.1 on Mac OS Catalina after installed [Fluter Storm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14718-fluter-storm/r) plug-in. So, I had to remove the plug-in under this folder and the problem was fixed. 

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins`

There was also Android Studio under `Application Support` but that wasn't the right one. It took me while to figure out. 

Didn't need to delete all plugins 

Answer (score 2):

Enable "Show hidden files and folders" in the explorer view settings.
and follow this path and delete "flutter storm":
C:\Users\owsb0\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same isssue on Ubuntu 20.04, here is what I did to fix it:**

Delete Android Studio

Delete folder ~/.AndroidStudio

Delete folder ~/.android

Delete folder ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio*

Delete folder ~/.gradle

Delete folder ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio*

Delete the Android sdk-folder (if not inside the android-studio dir)

I cleared the trash folder as well. Reboot, then re-install Android Studio. It should work now.

Comment: you just deleted everything, but it may not been required

Answer (score 0):

For the latest versions on macOS remove the plugins directory

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/<android_studio_version>/plugins
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins
```

or go to
`~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins` directory and remove the troublesome plugin you installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try also re-installing (uninstall then reinstall) Android Studio