# Android Studio Error: Key io.flutter.settings.FlutterSettings duplicated

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, error-handling, app-startup

I have issues with my android Studio, Every time I run it it brings this error. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling android Studio in a different location but its not working. Here's The error message:[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5exI.png)

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64329143/android-studio-updated-cannot-start-now-internal-error-thrown) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, run following command in Command Prompt as administrator:

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Restart your machine

Answer (score 0):

**FOR WINDOW 10**

My problem is gone after this solution  Try may be the solution for your problem too

Run following command in Command Prompt as administrator

```
 netsh winsock reset
```

Restart your machine

I found the solution here  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmWUrFIK8RY

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue in Windows, navigate to the following path:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\plugins
```

Make sure to change `UserName` with yours in the Users folder. Then permanently delete the Flutter Storm folder