# Gradle sync failed: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, android-studio, gradle

I have the following configuration:

- MacOS 11.0.1 (MacOS firewall is off)
- Android Studio 4.1.2
- Android Gradle plugin version 4.1.1
- Gradle version 6.5
- Java jdk version 1.8.0_251

Gradle build started to report an error in all my projects, so I guess it's not related to a specific project config (build.gradle etc.).

The same projects are building and working normally on the same Android Studio, Gradle and JDK versions on Windows.

Steps I already tried but didn't help:

- Rebuild project
- Invalidate caches / restart
- Reinstall Android Studio from scratch, followed instructions for complete uninstall ([How to completely uninstall Android Studio on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac))
- A clean install of freshly downloaded Android Studio from https://developer.android.com/studio
- Make a clean install using JetBrains Toolbox
- Manually add certificates (downloaded from browser) to both Android Studio (Preferences/Tools/Server certificates) and Java keystore
- Install Android Studio 4.2 beta 5
- Install a newer version of JDK (1.8.0_281)

Error details:
*Gradle sync failed: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target*

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'name-of-the-project'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.4/google-services-4.3.4.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.4/google-services-4.3.4.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.4.1/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.4.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.4.1/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.4.1.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

It seems like it is a network problem, but I tried to use different connection solutions with different providers, with and without VPN.

All mentioned files are accessible and I can download them from terminal using wget

```
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.4/google-services-4.3.4.pom
--2021-03-04 12:42:32--  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.4/google-services-4.3.4.pom
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 216.58.214.206
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|216.58.214.206|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1576 (1,5K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘google-services-4.3.4.pom.1’

google-services-4.3.4.pom.1                100%[=====================================================================================>]   1,54K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2021-03-04 12:42:32 (11,3 MB/s) - ‘google-services-4.3.4.pom.1’ saved [1576/1576]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been stuck with the exact same bug for several days, and like you I tried pretty much everything.

Finally I noticed something in Android Studio. I went to the Http Proxy preference tab and I saw a message saying

> You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to "localhost"....

I tried to override this value by putting the line :

`systemProp.https.proxyHost=`

In my project gradle.properties file and tadaaa ! It works, I don't really understand what happened though...

Hoping to be helpful ;)

Comment: Thanks! It seems like an improvised workaround, but it works for me :)

Comment: I have reinstalled Android Studio 3 times :(

Comment: You saved my life.. thanks a lot for this answer

Comment: Don't know why this worked but thanks for saving :)

Comment: "I went to the Http Proxy preference tab and I saw a message saying" , can you please tell where this "tab" in Android Studio for windows? I cant find it.

Comment: Hey, What should i put in the value?
`systemProp.https.proxyHost=???`

Comment: @OliverD nothing, to disable it ;)

Comment: using this line helped me understand that Proxyman was blocking the Android studio (2023)

Answer (score 6):

After additional research... for some reason, MacOS network proxy settings were changed and that was the reason for the warning Android Studio made:

> You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to "localhost"....

To fix this, go to

**System Preferences / Network / Advanced (for network you are using) / Proxy**

and unselect Web Proxy and Secure Web Proxy

Comment: This is the answer that i needed

Comment: "I went to the Http Proxy preference tab and I saw a message saying" , can you please tell where this "tab" in Android Studio for windows? I cant find it.

Comment: I do it, but still got the same warning :(

Comment: @OliverD try to override this setting with parameter in the first answer... add the 
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
in gradle.properties file. As it obviously is a network problem...

Comment: There were some rogue proxy settings on my mac. Unticked those, and all was good +1

Comment: save my day!!!!tks

Answer (score 1):

There another possible reason for not getting a valid certificate path.  The various plugins you use in your gradle build are not necessarily using the trust store that contains the certificates to validate the authenticity of the certificate in question. In my case, I could communicate with a given server using a browser with no certificate validating errors, but I couldn't do the same using the "maven-publish" plugin.  Why, because they are using different trust stores for certificate validation.  The "maven-publish" uses the trust store that java has been configured to use.  The default location is in directory $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security.  The browser is using your OS trust store. The java trust store can be changed using the system properties:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore,
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType
```

You can set them in the gradle.properties file using this format:

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore={path to your truststore}
```

You can also set them in you build.gradle.kts script using this format:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "{your truststore password")
```

Comment: Finally, something that worked, to fix ALL Gradle downloads. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75948144/8956093)

In my case a proxy software installed on my mac was the culprit.

I faced this when I was trying build project on my Macbook. I tried so many solutions but none worked. Finally saw that the IT team had installed a proxy software and suspected that the proxy software could be blocking gradle to download the dependencies. I connected with IT Team and got the proxy uninstalled and then synced the project and it worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search and trying all other options already answered, I found this setting in my gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djsse.enableSNIExtension\=false
```

This was because of a formerly (now removed) special corp requirement. I removed this setting and gradle build worked as normal.