# How can i reverse my android studio to escape this PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:..?

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, certificate

I recently updated my flutter version to 2.0.0 and it worked fine on **iOS** after updating the pub packages versions to the latest. It unfortunately didn't work on **Android** and i thought of updating the Android studio. Since then I have been getting certificate errors and I have tried the following, specified in other stackoverflow answers with no result:

1. adding certificates from maven,jcenter and google to jdk
2. changed build.gradle version several times
3. downloaded new sdk tools
4. accepted all licenses from `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
5. tried reinstalling an old flutter and running an app from it
6. downloaded new jdks

.. all to no avail
At this point, I just want my old android back :(

> build.gradle

```
/*
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
}
```

> gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Sat Mar 06 06:08:23 MSK 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

> Error message

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ActivitySceneTransitionBasic'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have this same issue and you have tried everything you found on stack overflow.. this solved it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66549260/11320345

> Add `systemProp.https.proxyHost=` to your gradle-wrapper.properties file

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66572690/11320345

> Unselect proxies in your system preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> (Your current network)

NOTE: I would also like to add that after i followed the step number 2, undoing step 1 worked for flutter related projects