# Android Studio analyzing infinity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a problem: My android studio is analyzing infinitely:

I have tried:

- uninstalling Android Studio
- Invalidate cashes / Restart
- restart my computer.

build.gradle (Project)

[image]

build.gradle (Module)

[image]

Main Activity (Analyzing text top right corner)

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: I am using latest android studio version: 4.2.1

Comment: Is it a preview build? if so then it might an issue with the android studio itself.

Comment: No, it is a stable build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I fully deleted my android studio with all connected files using [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac) and then reinstalled its new stable (the same 4.2.1. version). The problem was solved.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to Upgrade the latest kotlin version.

1. Upgrade the dependency in the project's build.gradle file.

   ```
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
   ```
2. Upgrade the dependency in the app's build.gradle file.

   ```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.10"
   ```

Comment: The most recommended answer

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issues.
I Follow below step:
Close Project
Delete all “.idea” & ".gradle” folder

Answer (score 0):

Want to solve this problem, you need to download the kotlin plugin with the version 202-1.5.0-release-764-AS8194.7 at this website https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions, then install it.