# Android Studio 4.2 analyzing code take forever

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.2

I'm currently using Android Studio version 4.2.1 (mac OS). While opening a Kotlin file, it shows "Analyzing" in the top right corner as shown in the attached image, forever! Here're what I already did

- Clean / Rebuild the project, no luck
- Restart the program, no luck
- Invalidate cache and restart, no luck

and here're what I will certainly not do (please do not recommend me to do the following)

- reinstall the program
- format the computer

It's a ***stable*** version by the way. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio analyzing infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67665127/android-studio-analyzing-infinity)