# Mac Keybord touch (suppr, enter, tab ...) don't work on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, macos-big-sur

I am on Mac OS Big Sur version 11.4 and i develop  flutter app using Android Studio, when i started the IDE work well, but know i can't use suppr, tab or enter on the keybord, they don't work, i can only tap text but can't suppr them or enter ...
suppr work the first time i click on it but in the second time or more it doesn't work.
thank you for your help

I use Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable •
Tools • Dart 2.14.4
Android Studio Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Mac M1 Apple Chip

Comment: I have tried uninstall and install Android Studio but it doesn't resolve the matter

Answer (score 0):

[How to completely uninstall Android Studio on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)

rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/.gradle
rm -Rf ~/.android
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*
rm -Rf /usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/

i resolve doing this after uninstall and reinstall android studio