# Android Studio fails trying to sync Gradle project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm running Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1 on macOS. I'm trying to sync Gradle (because the Gradle tab doesn't appear on the right of the screen) and it fails when building with this error:

```
org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationInvocationException: SDK Registry token is null. See README.md for more details.
```

Here's how it happens.

First, I open my app/build.gradle.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.delete_me"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Next, I see this above the file.

[image]

Next, I click it and downloading and building begins.

Finally I run into the error.

[image]

[image]

I've tried invalidating caches, removing .gradle from my home directory, and restarting Android Studio, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also now removed Android Studio entirely (per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac), reinstalled it and the problem remains.