# Losing all network connectivity when running android studio emulators with flutter apps

Tags: flutter, android-studio, network-connection

I am having network connectivity issues when running flutter apps with the Android studio emulator. I am not talking about accessing the internet on the emulator, my actual computer that is running android studio, loses all network connectivity.

When running android studio emulators with flutter apps I get the following:

1. flutter doctor -v it states there is an issue with the HTTP HOST.
2. I can not access any webpages via the chrome browser or safari.
3. Ping in terminal shows no connectivity.

I can run the flutter apps on IOS emulators with no problems.

I have tried deleting and reloading the emulators.

Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: on the emulator , try to turn off and on the wifi again.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not solve the problem.  I also tried reseting my computers wifi connection and that did not help either. A complete reinstall of android studio seems to be helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I had to do the following.

1. From the terminal I ran: brew uninstall android-sdk
2. Then I used terminal to completely uninstall android stuido from my mac, referencing this post:

   [How to completely uninstall Android Studio on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)
3. I downloaded and reinstalled android studio and the emulators.