# how to uninstall Andriod studio flamingo

Tags: android, uninstallation, android-studio-flamingo

I mistakenly install android studio flamingo, i want to uninstall it and want to install the android studio IDE. I using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac) answer but the (*) commands are not working
it says this.

```
zsh: no matches found: /Users/[name]/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
```

Actually i'm trying to setup flutter, so for this i need to this all. I want to reinstall everything from fresh.

------UPDATE

i am facing this issue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:669)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:651)
```

here is my current version of java

```
java version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and flutter version is 3.7.0

Please help how to fix this issue.

Comment: You are aware that Android Studio Flamingo **is** the current Android Studio IDE?

Comment: i got to know it now! but i am facing the issue, i updated my question please check it.

Comment: Android Studio comes with built-in Java 17. use that version instead of the 20 (which is a non-LTS version which means it is only useful for certain Java developers).

Comment: i have installed the java 20, now how to uninstall it?