# How can I use an application from another project as a library?

Tags: java, android, gradle, hierarchy, exoplayer

How can I use an application from another project as a library, when that application depends on a library that I am already using?

Here’s what I have:

```
MyProject
  app
  libraries
    ExoPlayer
      demo
      library
```

Here's my current configuration as it pertains to this.

demo/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

library/build.gradle:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

MyProject/settings.gradle:

`include ':libraries:ExoPlayer:library'`

MyProject/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:ExoPlayer:library')
}
```

As you can see I’m using ExoPlayer library as a library (go figure) but I want to use demo application as a library as well (specifically for the DemoPlayer, I don't want the activities). But demo also has a dependency on library. What do I have to put in my gradle files to achieve this?

I tried to follow the library setup and apply it to demo but it broke the demo build:

```
Project with path ':library' could not be found in project ':libraries:ExoPlayer:demo'
```

I have tried following other similar threads such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16971375/432311) but with no success.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It's not constructive to downvote a question without saying why. What is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I've use Exoplayer as a library project but it's not needed anymore : you can use gradle dependencies :

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.4.2'
```

If you want to persist with library project, you will have to check your `settings.gradle` where all Android Studio referenced module are in. This file contain the name of module as you will use it after.

**Example** : (based on [AndroidVuMeter](https://github.com/HugoGresse/AndroidVuMeter))

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app', ':vumeterlibrary'
```

**project structure**

```
Project/
   app/
   vumeterlibrary/
```

To use `vumeterlibrary` you will have to use `compile project(':vumeterlibrary')` in your app `build.gradle`

Comment: That looks like exactly what I tried above, but with different project stucture. Can the argument to `compile project` be a path to a subproject or does it have to be in the root project folder?

Comment: You not need to use a sub-project pass, but the projet name like `yourlibrary` which is defined in your root `settings.gradle`. Dont hesitate to check out the AndroidVuMeter library Linked in my answer